# How to use Path.GetInvalidPathChars to find a file name inside a larger string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

My goal is to find a file name ("MyFile.txt") inside a larger string. I.e.:

> *Some text before* **MyFile.txt** *some other text after*

Currently I'm successfully using a Regular Expression with a character class of something like the following (simplified):

```
[\w\.\-]
```

This works fine, until the file contains other characters that are outside the `\w` group, e.g. an em dash: "My—File.txt".

**My approach:**

The method [`Path.GetInvalidPathChars`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars) returns an array of *invalid* characters. I've tried to use this method. Unfortunately, I found no way of "converting" this to be useful inside a Regular Expression.

I'm aware of

- The SO posting "[How to remove illegal characters from path and filenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146134/how-to-remove-illegal-characters-from-path-and-filenames)"
- The concept of "[Character class subtraction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#CharacterClassSubtraction)"

Still, I found no solution.

**My question:**

Is there any Regular Expression (or any other way) to find and extract a file name inside a larger string, based on the result of `Path.GetInvalidPathChars`?

Comment: This is a very difficult thing - there is no safe regex way to extract arbitrary file names from larger texts.

Comment: You´d have to build a regex for searching strings that do *not* contain any of the invalid characters. But this could be *anything*, even files without extension exist - at least on Windows.

Comment: @jdweng I'm doing it for convenience, since a dash is a special character in `a-z`.

Comment: Can you post some more samples?

Comment: You also have to limit what the names of the file can be - e.g. `.txt` files. Files don't need to have extensions. or can have spaces and "@" characters. or start with a dot.

Comment: Does your filename contain spaces?

Comment: If you _had_ to do it using re, how about https://regex101.com/r/dRWjqr/1? As most have already pointed out, this is a very difficult task, and would need a lot of assumptions on the dataset for it to work correctly

Comment: Ideally, I think I a feature to define my own negative character group (like `\W`) would be the solution. Unfortunately, this is not possible in .NET.

Comment: See my edit, it should work with regex now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won´t use a regex for this at all as it becomes incredibly complex and unreadable. In particular a filename could be nearly *any* string, including most special characters, numbers, spaces. Even worse there are even files without a dot to seperate an extension. So I´d suggest to simply do an `Contains`-check on all your invalid characters:

```
char[] invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars;
bool valid = !myString.Contains(x => invalidChars.Contains(x));
```

Extracting the candidates instead is even simpler. The idea is to split your large string on all invalid characters. This means everything in between the invalid characters is considered a file-name, e.g:

> `"myTest.extension"` → `"myTest.extension"`
>   `"myFile:anotherFile"` → `"myFile"; "anotherFile"`
>   `"myFile with space"` → `"myFile with space"`
>   `"a File with .-determined extension.dot"` → `"a File with .-determined extension.dot"`

This is achieved by this code:

```
var fileNames = myText.Split(invalidChars);
```

EDIT: If you really want a regex you can build one dynamically from your invalid characters:

```
var pattern = String.Format("([^{0}]*)", new String(invalidCharacters));
var r = new Regex(pattern);
```

Comment: Only part of my string is a file name, not the whole string. Plus: I do not want to check true/false, I want to get the string.

Comment: No -1 from me. The `Split` idea looks nice!

Comment: Instead `String.Join("", invalidCharacters.Select(x => x.ToString()))` I do prefer [`new string(invalidCharacters)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9(v=vs.110).aspx) .

Comment: `String.Join("", ` is now unnecessary, I guess. I've removed it in your code, hope this is OK.

Answer (score 0):

If your file name do not contains space and *do* contain extension, then this simple idea may help you

```
string line = "Some text before MyFile.txt some other text after";

//If you look for path:
//var array = Path.GetInvalidPathChars().ToList();

//If you look for file name
var array = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().ToList();
array.Add(' ');

var potentialFileNames = line.Split(array.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                             .Where(i => i.Contains('.')).ToList();

 //potentialFileNames[0] = "MyFile.txt"
```

Comment: I convert it to add the space before using it in split