# Google can't crawl generated CSS and JS paths originating from Custom outputcache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, outputcache

I have set up Custom Outputcache for my website. Everything works as intended, I can see the cache folder with the binary files. When I visit the site I get the cached pages and it renders as it should.

The problem is that when I try to use Google webmaster tools to render the page, Google can't access the generated css path generated in the BundleConfig `~/bundles/styles/maincss/`, the same goes to the javascript path.`. When I visit those two paths I get to see the minified JS and CSS files and the browser does render the page correctly.

This poses an issue, because now when I test the page using mobile-test tool, I get that the pages are not mobile friendly. For some reason Google can't access those paths, although when I run the web crawl in webmaster tools, it does render good for the user, but not for Google-bot.

This worked when I don't use the Custom output caching, only the default Outputcache.

Any idea how to tackle this issue.

Custom outputcache code:

Web.config:

```
</connectionStrings> 
 <appSettings>
   <add key="CacheLocation" value="~/Cache"/>
 </appSettings>
 <system.web>
   <caching>
     <outputCache defaultProvider="FileCache">
       <providers>
        <add name="FileCache" type="ProjectX.FileCacheProvider"/>
    </providers>
  </outputCache>
</caching>
```

Caching Class:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Caching;

namespace ProjectX
{
    [Serializable]
    public class CacheItem
    {
        public object Item { get; set; }
        public DateTime Expiry { get; set; }
    }

    public class FileCacheProvider : OutputCacheProvider
    {
        private string CacheLocation
        {
            get
            {
                string strCacheLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CacheLocation"];
                strCacheLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(strCacheLocation);
                return strCacheLocation + @"\";
            }
        }


        private string GetFullPathForKey(string key)
        {
            string temp = key.Replace('/', '$');
            return CacheLocation + temp;
        }

        public override object Add(string key, object entry, DateTime utcExpiry)
        {
            object obj = this.Get(key);
            if (obj != null)
            {
                return obj;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Set(key, entry, utcExpiry);
                return entry;
            }
        }

        public override void Remove(string key)
        {
            string filePath = GetFullPathForKey(key);
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                File.Delete(filePath);
            }
        }

        public override object Get(string key)
        {
            string filePath = GetFullPathForKey(key);
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                return null;
            }
            CacheItem item = null;
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            item = (CacheItem)formatter.Deserialize(fileStream);
            fileStream.Close();
            if (item == null || item.Expiry <= DateTime.UtcNow)
            {
                Remove(key);
                return null;
            }
            return item.Item;
        }



        public override void Set(string key, object entry, DateTime utcExpiry)
        {
            string filePath = GetFullPathForKey(key);
            CacheItem item = new CacheItem { Expiry = utcExpiry, Item = entry };
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(filePath);
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(fileStream, item);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mjwills I updated the question with the code.

Comment: If you put a `Thread.Sleep(5000)` both before and after `FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(filePath);` flush your browser cache, restart IIS and then load the same JS resource in two separate browsers (say Chrome and Firefox) at the same time do you get an error because two things are trying to write to the file at the same time?

Comment: @mjwills I don't get an error, Google can't access it. I initiated a crawl in webmaster tools several times and it still wasn't able to access it. I am able with my browser to access it. When Google access it, it should be read from the same cache, not writing anything to the cache.

Comment: @mjwills I get The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Idan\Desktop\projectx\projectx_project\projectxx\Cache\a2$bundles$styles$maincss$' because it is being used by another process.'

Comment: I also get System.NotSupportedException: 'The given path's format is not supported.'. used in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: You'll need to fix that too. Is there a specific reason you want to use a custom cache? Why not use the default one?

Comment: @mjwills because I have some pages with long query. Sometimes after restart of a pool or update of files those need to recached. Like this, this is not dependent on the ASP pipeline and when I update the web.config for example, the cache continue to be served for the cache.

Comment: @mjwills I think they main reason for that is that the cache append the user agent to the file name and the filename is just broken. Don't know why it works like that, because I want to serve the same page regardless of the user agent.

Comment: @mjwills this is an unusual name for the cache item a2$bundles$styles$maincss$HNHTTP_USER_AGENTVMozilla$5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit$537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome$59.0.3071.109 Safari$537.36QFCDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to continue down this path (I assume you have used https://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/asp-net-4-0-writing-custom-output-cache-providers as your starting point?), you will need to change `GetFullPathForKey` so that it generates valid filenames. [How to remove illegal characters from path and filenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146134/how-to-remove-illegal-characters-from-path-and-filenames) will likely help you do that. You will also need to change your code so that it doesn't fall over if two threads try and write to the same file at the same time. Plus you really should introduce the use of a `MemoryCache` to avoid hitting the file system every time a `Get` call to your class occurs. *This will be a lot of work.*

I would suggest considering these NuGet packages as an alternative. They do this stuff out of the box, and are well tested:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisOutputCacheProvider/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/CacheManager.Web/

Or just whack a reverse proxy in front of the web server which assists with caching - e.g. http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/the-benefits-of-reverse-proxy.html .