# AppDomain.DynamicDirectory is not generated

Tags: c#, appdomain, vstest.console.exe, appdomainsetup

I am creating a AppDomain using the below code

```
String pa = @"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\2\db5fjamk.xnl";
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pa);
AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
setup.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; //f:\projectpath\out\debug-i386-unittest\UnitTests
setup.ApplicationName = string.Concat(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks); //UnitTestAdapter: Running test636559691791186101
setup.DynamicBase = pa;
Evidence evidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence;
_Domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(setup.ApplicationName, evidence, setup);
```

But _Domain.DynamicDirectory property does not exist. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.dynamicdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx clearly says the AppDomainSetup.DynamicBase is used.

What could be the reason executing in vstest.console.exe changes the behavior with App Domains. Is there a work around.

Comment: Where are you trying to access `_Domain.DynamicDirectory`?  I don't see it in your code at all.

Comment: I am doing it in next line using _Domain.DynamicDirectory. Which throws error 'The given path's format is not supported.', inspecting _Domain shows it does not even have property defined

Comment: which version of .net are you using?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.6.2

Comment: You will have to go slower.  "inspecting _Domain" is not going to help you, it is a proxy.  Use `var path = _Domain.DynamicDirectory;` and tell us exactly what you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

Check if the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName` contains illegal characters such as a colon (:). If yes you should sanitize `setup.ApplicationName` with one of the methods discussed in the SO question [How to remove illegal characters from path and filenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146134/how-to-remove-illegal-characters-from-path-and-filenames).

**Background**

When I debugged the test I got a `System.NotSupportedException` with the message `The given path's format is not supported.`.

The stack trace was

```
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
at System.AppDomain.get_DynamicDirectory()
at System.AppDomain.get_DynamicDirectory()
at SO_AppDomain.Sut.Method() in <path>\Program.cs:line 30
at UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in <path>\UnitTest1.cs:line 14
```

And the value of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName` was `TestSourceHost: Enumering assembly`.

A quick look at the [reference source of `EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/pathinternal.cs,c6ce0a4dfda921b3) - which is the last method that appears in the stack trace - revealed that it throws a `NotSupportedException` if [`PathInternal.HasInvalidVolumeSeparator`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/pathinternal.cs,c6ce0a4dfda921b3) returns true. That method contains the following comment:

```
 // Toss out paths with colons that aren't a valid drive specifier.
 // Cannot start with a colon and can only be of the form "C:" or "\\?\C:".
```

The string `TestSourceHost: Enumering assembly` clearly violates that rule.

Comment: It worked.  Just a doubt so with stack trace how did you endup realising that it is because of illegal character in friendly name.

Comment: I edited my answer and tried to clarify my line of thought when I looked at the stack trace and the reference source code.