# How to check for illegal file/folder names in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, io, filenames

I'm making a small program that will auto generate all of the files that I need to make a website like `index.html` and `style.css` so when I make a new site it will be easy to start coding. I want to make my program not accept any illegal file/folder names and characters into the text box. I just dont want the `<>:/|\?*` but I also want the names like `con` and `nul` to not work.

I am using c# winforms with Visual Studio 2019 and dotnet 3

If anyone has an answer please tell me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove illegal characters from path and filenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146134/how-to-remove-illegal-characters-from-path-and-filenames). You have to check yourself to remove `con` and `nul`, because they could be part of a legitimate filename (like `consolidations.txt` or `nullvaluesfromtable.txt`).

Comment: `that will auto generate all of the files` If you are auto generating, call them whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

The characters that are not allowed in a **file name** are available from the [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars) method (but note the "Remarks" section in the documentation). For the [reserved file names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file), I'm not aware of a method to get them, so you would have to compare against all of them explicitely:

```
bool IsValidFileName(string name)
{
    // empty names are not allowed
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        return false;
    
    // check for characters that are not allowed in a file name
    if (Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Any(c => name.Contains(c))
        return false;
    
    // check for reserved names
    if (name.Equals(".", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("..", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("CON", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("PRN", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("AUX", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("NUL", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("COM1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("COM2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("COM3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("COM4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("COM5", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("COM6", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("COM7", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("COM8", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("COM9", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("LPT1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("LPT2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("LPT3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("LPT4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("LPT5", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("LPT6", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("LPT7", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("LPT8", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || name.Equals("LPT9", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return false;
        
    return true;
}
```

For checking **path names**, you can use the similar [Path.GetInvalidPathChars()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars) method:

```
bool IsValidPathName(string name)
{
    // empty path is not allowed
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        return false;
    
    // check for characters that are not allowed in a path name
    if (Path.GetInvalidPathChars().Any(c => name.Contains(c))
        return false;
    
    // check the file name part
    if (!IsValidFileName(Path.GetFileName(name))
        return false;
        
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just dont want the <>:/|?*

To achieve this, you can try to use Regex to exclude them.

```
// if contains the characters, return true
bool containsChar = Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"[<>:/|\\?*]");
```

> but I also want the names like con and nul to not work

Do you want to exclude `con` and `nul` as filename, or do you not allow these substrings in the string? If the latter, you can refer to the code as followed.

```
// array to store excluded substring
string[] excludesubstring = { "con", "nul" };
bool containsSubstr = false;

foreach (string str in excludesubstring)
{
    if (containsSubstr = textBox1.Text.Contains(str) == true)
        break;
}
```

Last, use the following to check if it is a valid filename.

```
if (containsChar || containsSubstr)
{
    Console.WriteLine("filename includes invalid content");
}
```