# How can I strip unwanted characters from a string in python?

Tags: python, string, text

I have the following string:

```
text = 'adsfklaiin2007daf adf adflkajf;j 2008afadfkjkj'
```

I want to return:

```
2007 2008
```

Any way to do this in Python?

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450897/python-removing-characters-except-digits-from-string/1450900#1450900

Comment: What if it's a specific text I want to keep. It might be a number but it might not. For example, what if I wanted to keep 2007d 2008a or some other particular string of text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'adsfklaiin2007daf adf adflkajf;j 2008afadfkjkj'
>>> re.sub("[^0-9]"," ",text)
'          2007                   2008         '
```

I will leave it to you to format the output.

Answer (score 7):

This is a classic case for regular expressions. Using the re python library you get:

```
re.findall('\d{4}', "yourStringHere")
```

This will return a list of all four digit items found in the string. Simply adjust your regex as needed.

Answer (score 5):

```
import re
num = re.compile('[\d]*')
numbers = [number for number in num.findall(text) if number]
['2007', '2008']
```

Answer (score 1):

[str.translate](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html)

```
text.translate(None, ''.join(chr(n) for n in range(0xFF) if chr(n) not in ' 01234567890')
```

You can probably construct a better table of characters to skip and make it prettier, but that's the general idea.