# Delete letters from string

Tags: python

I have strings like '12454v', '346346z'. I want to delete all letters from strings.

Re works fine:

```
import re
str='12454v'
re.sub('[^0-9]','', str)

#return '12454'
```

Is there a way to do this without using regular expressions?

Comment: @kojiro I stand corrected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, '12454v'))
'12454'
```

Answer (score 4):

In python 2 the second argument to the `translate` method allows you to specify characters to delete

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate

The example given shows that you can use `None` as a translation table to *just* delete characters:

```
>>> 'read this short text'.translate(None, 'aeiou')
'rd ths shrt txt'
```

(You can get a list of all ASCII letters from the string module as `string.letters`.)

**Update**: Python 3 also has a `translate` method, though it requires a slightly different setup:

```
from string import ascii_letters
tr_table = str.maketrans({c:None for c in ascii_letters})
'12345v'.transate(tr_table)
```

For the record, using translation tables in Python 2 is *much*, *much* faster than the join/filter method:

```
>>> timeit("''.join(filter(lambda c:not c.isalpha(), '12454v'))")
2.698641061782837
>>> timeit("''.join(filter(str.isdigit, '12454v'))") 
1.9351119995117188
>>> timeit("'12454v'.translate(None, string.letters)", "import string")
0.38182711601257324
```

Likewise in Python 3:

```
>>> timeit("'12454v'.translate(tr_table)", "import string; tr_table=str.maketrans({c:None for c in string.ascii_letters})")
0.6507143080000333
>>> timeit("''.join(filter(lambda c:not c.isalpha(), '12454v'))")
2.436105844999929
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try this with `.translate` method.

```
>>> import string
>>> str='12454v'
>>> str.translate(None, string.letters)
'12454'
```

There is a very good answer about `.translate` method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450897/python-removing-characters-except-digits-from-string).

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat less elegant than the others because it's not using a specific function and is somewhat more clunky:

```
newStr = ''
myStr='12454v'
for char in myStr:
    try:
        newStr += str(int(char))
    except ValueError:
        pass
print newStr
```

Again, this isn't best way, but I'm just throwing it out there.
I converted it to an `int` first so that it can check whether or not is an integer. Then, I convert it to a `str` so that it can be added to `newStr`.

On another note, you shouldn't use `str` as a variable name because it shadows the built-in function `str()`.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.10 I had to do the following:

```py
import string
l = string.ascii_letters
trans = "".maketrans(l, l, l)
s = "123abc"
s = s.translate(trans)
```