# Removing non numeric characters from text file Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been given the task to remove all non numeric characters including spaces from a text file and then print the new result next to the old characters for example:

Before:

```
sd67637 8

ssheiej44
```

After:

```
sd67637 8 = 676378

ssheiej44 = 44
```

As i am a beginner i do not know where to start with this task. I followed instructions from another user but i wasnt as clear to elaborate this is what i have so far.

```
text1 = open('/Users/student/Desktop/Harry.txt', 'r')
data = text1.readlines()
new_string = ''.join(ch for ch in data if ch.isdigit())
print(data, '=', new_string)
```

Yet it still doesnt give me the desired effect as shown above. Instead i get this:

```
    [] =
```

Could someone please fix this and explain in laymens terms please.

Comment: Just answered your [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336943/removing-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string) - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17337324/1561176)

Comment: You are opening an empty file, or need to reopen it. If your code is printing `[]` for `data`, then `.readlines()` returned an *empty list*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not *call* the `text1.readlines` method. Add `()`:

```
data = text1.readlines()
```

Note that a file object such as `text1` can work as an iterator. There is no need to call `.readlines()`; just loop over `text1` *directly*. Your code still needs adjustment; both `.readlines()` and `text1` give you a sequence of *lines*:

```
for line in text1:
     new_string = ''.join(ch for ch in line if ch.isdigit())
     print(data, '=', new_string)
```

In your version, `ch` was assigned a whole line from the file at a time, and since each line contains at least a newline, `.isdigit()` would *always* be False.

Comment: +1, I feel like `.readlines()` should just be removed due to all the confusion it generates. `list(f)` also works fine

Comment: i did what martijin said now i get absolutley nothing in the console

Comment: @Obcure: Did you reopen the file?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes ive even recreated a whole new file still no luck

Comment: @Obcure: First make `print(open('....').read())` work; if you see data with that call, then you have a file with data.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes i did that copied it before the code you gave me so i get what is in the file but then blank after that

Comment: And if you say `new_string = line`, comment out the other `new_string =` line, inside the loop, what is printed then?

Comment: @MartijnPieters same as before

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32460/discussion-between-obcure-and-martijn-pieters)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same answer I gave you on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336943/removing-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17337324/1561176).

```
from string import ascii_letters

with open('/Users/student/Desktop/Harry.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print (line, '=', line.translate(None, ascii_letters+' '))
```