# Translate function in Python 3

Tags: python, function, translate

I am using Python 3 and I want to translate my file names to have no numbers. The translate function doesn't seem to work in Python 3. How can I translate the file names to have no numbers?

This is the block of code that doesn't work:

```
file_name = "123hello.jpg"
file_name.translate(None, "0123456789")
```

Thanks

Comment: are you sure you can define `file_name = 123hello.jpg` ? O_o

Answer (score 54):

[`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) is still there, the interface has just changed a little:

```
>>> table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys('0123456789'))
>>> '123hello.jpg'.translate(table)
'hello.jpg'
```

Comment: A little bit confusing but it works. THANKS YOU

Answer (score 8):

`.translate` takes a translation table:

> Return a copy of the string S in which each character has been
>   mapped
>       through the given translation table. The table must implement
>       lookup/indexing via **getitem**, for instance a dictionary or list,
>       mapping Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals, strings, or None. If
>       this operation raises LookupError, the character is left untouched.
>       Characters mapped to None are deleted.

So you can do something like:

```
>>> file_name = "123hello.jpg"
>>> file_name.translate({ord(c):'' for c in "1234567890"})
'hello.jpg'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Only remove numbers from the left

```
new_name = old_name.lstrip('1234567890')
```

Only remove numbers from the right

```
new_name = old_name.rstrip('1234567890')
```

Remove number from left and right

```
new_name = old_name.strip('1234567890')
```

Remove all numbers

```
new_name = old_name.translate(old_name.maketrans('', '', '1234567890'))
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using ver3.6.1 and str.translate did not work. What did work is the *strip* method:

```py
file_name = '123hello.jpg'
file_name.strip('123')
```

Comment: This doesn't cover remove '1', '2', or '3' from the string, but removing the substring '123'.  Not exactly what was asked, although it does "fix" the example code.

Comment: @boatcoder The `strip` function interprets '123' as the set of chars to remove, so it will remove '1', '2' or '3' from the string

Comment: @nonagon `>>> "1 apple, 2 oranges, 3 pigs".strip("123")` produces
`' apple, 2 oranges, 3 pigs'`
This does NOT work for a general case.  He wants to remove numbers from the filename all over, not only at the begining.  This solves the one example case but not the problem.

Comment: @boatcoder Aha sorry I misunderstood your comment - I agree!