# How to make all the bits inverted in python?

Tags: python, math, binary, bit

I want to convert these binary representation as follows.

```
"1111" -> "0000"
"1010" -> "0101"
```

Comment: as i don't want to loop through strings.

Comment: Convert to int, xor with 15 and convert back to binary string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Translate function in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708770/translate-function-in-python-3)

Comment: It sounds like you want a function that takes an integer and returns an integer; is that right?  Or do you actually want to take and return a string?

Comment: Both are find because it can be converted to integer and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert

```
 "0100" to "1011",         simply 0100(your input string) ^ 1111(maskbit)         = "1011"

 "11110000" to "00001111", simply 11110000(your input string) ^ 11111111(maskbit) = "00001111"
```

We can see a pattern here,

> len(mask bit) = len(binary input string)

Based on the above observations,

```
def invertBits(num): 

     mask='1'*len(num)                       #This produces bit mask needed for the conversion
     answer=int(num,2)^int(mask,2)           #Inversion process happens here (XOR)

     print(answer,bin(answer).lstrip("0b")); #This would give both the integer equivalent and the pattern of the inverted bits as a string

invertBits("0100")                           #The output will be "11 1011"
```

The method `int(num,2)` takes "`num`" argument as a string and base="`2`" here(binary format)

Answer (score 6):

Hope you are looking something like this,

```
def convert(inp):
    return ''.join(['1','0'][int(i)] for i in inp)
convert('1010')
```

output

```
0101
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a method to do that, but it takes several type conversion. Not sure if there is better way to do that.

```
def f(x:str):
    return  '%04d' % int(bin(int(x, 2) ^ 15)[2:])

print(f("0000"))
print(f("0011"))
print(f("1010"))
print(f("1111"))
```

```
output:
1111
1100
0101
0000
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at python but I think this is right because it worked on my computer.

```
num = input()
answer = ""
for i in range(0, len(num)):
    if num[i] == "0":
        answer += "1"
    elif num[i] == "1":
        answer += "0"
print(answer)
```

input:

```
0000
```

output:

```
1111
```