# Python string.translate throws type error for string format (ddd)ddd-dddd

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, unicode

I need to format some phone numbers, the format that I want is `'(ddd)ddd-dddd'`. I stole the code from [Python: removing characters except digits from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450897/python-removing-characters-except-digits-from-string), and as always voted it up. It works fine, for the most part, but there is something happening that I do not understand.

I have a Django model named `CustomerStudent`, which has a `cell_phone` and `business_phone` field. My save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.cell_phone = format_phone(self.cell_phone)
    self.business_phone = format_phone(self.business_phone)
    super(CustomerStudent, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The `format_phone` method is in my `util.py` file.

```
def format_phone(str=None):
    if str is None:
        return str
    all = string.maketrans('', '')
    nodigs=all.translate(all, string.digits)
    raw_phone = str.translate(all, nodigs)
    if len(raw_phone) == 10:
        pass
    elif len(raw_phone) == 7:
        raw_phone = '000' + raw_phone
    else:
        return None
    return '(%s)%s-%s' % (raw_phone[0:3:1], raw_phone[3:6:1], raw_phone[6::1])
```

I was writing tests to check this model when I encountered this problem.

The test model was built using the following values:

```
cell_phone = '5555555555'
business_phone = '999-9999'
```

tests.py

```
s = CustomerStudent.objects.get(pk=1)
self.assertEqual(s.cell_phone, '(555)555-5555') # Passes
self.assertEqual(s.business_phone, '(000)999-9999') # Passes
s.cell_phone = 'a5-55l7i77(7/7e7p7-)'
s.save()
self.assertEqual(s.cell_phone, '(555)777-7777') # Passes
self.assertEqual(s.business_phone, '(000)999-9999') # Fails
```

The error mesasage:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.........E............
======================================================================
ERROR: test_customer_student (training.tests.TrainingTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/path/to/app/tests.py", line 281, in test_customer_student
s.save()
File "/path/to/app/models.py", line 149, in save
self.business_phone = format_phone(self.business_phone)
File "path/to/app/util.py", line 16, in format_phone
raw_phone = str.translate(all, nodigs)
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 22 tests in 0.968s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I know that Unicode behaves differently, but I made sure that all of the characters from a properly formatted phone number were present in the new phone number. I decided to catch the `TypeError` and return `None`.

```
def format_phone(str=None):
    if str is None:
        return str
    all = string.maketrans('', '')
    nodigs=all.translate(all, string.digits)
    try:
        raw_phone = str.translate(all, nodigs)
    except TypeError:
        return None
    if len(raw_phone) == 10:
        pass
    elif len(raw_phone) == 7:
        raw_phone = '000' + raw_phone
    else:
        return None
    return '(%s)%s-%s' % (raw_phone[0:3:1], raw_phone[3:6:1], raw_phone[6::1])
```

Now when I run the tests:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.........F............
======================================================================
FAIL: test_customer_student (training.tests.TrainingTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/path/to/app/tests.py", line 283, in  test_customer_student
self.assertEqual(s.business_phone, '(000)999-9999')
AssertionError: None != '(000)999-9999'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 22 tests in 0.954s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Now for the question. Why does this happen when the number is not changed? I believe it is related to Unicode but the new `cell_number` has the same characters in it and it runs through `format_phone` correctly.

I could probably get around this by checking to see if the phone numbers have changed in the save method, but that just seems like avoidable overhead. Suggestions?

Comment: Do you try to add a `print(str, type(str))` at the beginning of `format_phone` function? And IMHO, it's a bad idea to use `str` as variable's name.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? Is it reserved?

Comment: Oops, now I see and I agree, I will change it. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, and yes the return from `format_phone` is Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the use of regular string with:

```
def format_phone(phone_str=None):
    phone_str = phone_str.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    [...]
```

as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365411/python-convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors)