# Is there an elegant way to strip all alphabetic characters from the end of a string?

Tags: python, string, strip

This works:

```
stripped_str = whatever_str.rstrip("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
```

but just seems very inelegant to me. Any cleaner way of doing it?

Comment: this is a vague question. definitions of "clean" and "elegant" are subjective, and they often depend on how the code is going to be used.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450897/python-removing-characters-except-digits-from-string

Comment: @heri0n that's not related... this is asking how to strip from the *end* of the string, not how to remove character *anywhere* in the string...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [`string.ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters):

```
from string import ascii_letters
stripped_str = whatever_str.rstrip(ascii_letters)
```

It allows you to do the same as your current code, but without typing the entire alphabet.

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> from string import ascii_letters
>>> ascii_letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>>
>>> '123abdjihdkffyifbgh'.rstrip(ascii_letters)
'123'
>>>
```