# Eliminate numbers in string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I’d like to eliminate numbers in a string in Python.

```
str = "aaaa22222111111kkkkk"
```

I want this to be `"aaaakkkkk"`.

I use `re.sub` to replace, but it doesn't work:

```
str = "aaaa22222111111kkkkk"
str = re.sub(r'^[0-9]+$',"",str)
```

Maybe, this replaces a string which only contains numbers with `""`.

How should I do with this?

Comment: You don't need `^` and `$`.

Comment: ... or the `+` symbol

Comment: not exact duplicate IMO, since this is about regex.

Comment: Related: [removing characters except digits from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450897/python-removing-characters-except-digits-from-string)

Comment: This is not the same question.Also the doubts of OP are different.Nominated for reopening

Comment: Don't need to reopen, since the answer is in the comments. `^` represents the start of a line and `$` represents the end of the line. So your regex will remove those lines which contains only digits.

Comment: since you are not looking for negative numbers, `not str.isdigit()` would be better. `"".join([x for x in s if not x.isdigit()])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your regex is wrong:

```
re.sub(r'[0-9]',"",str)
```

should work:

```
>>> str="aaaa22222111111kkkkk"
>>> re.sub(r'[0-9]',"",str)
'aaaakkkkk'
```

Comment: Thanks you.I found what was wrong.But this question seems to be controversial.I don't know what to do so I'll let it go.

Comment: str is a bad variable name