# How to extract number values from a list of paths and store them in a list removing other strings

Tags: python

```
list= ['/xyz/abc/def/123621912.csv',
 '/xyz/abc/def/1662828716.csv',
 '/xyz/abc/def/1111111111.csv',
 '/xyz/abc/def/7272718119.csv',
 '/xyz/abc/def/92881991911.csv',
 '/xyz/abc/def/66271819112.csv',
 '/xyz/abc/def/2717178192.csv']
```

This is a list . I want to extract a list having only integers

```
list = ['123621912,1662828716,1111111111,7272718119,92881991911,66271819112,2717178192]
```

I tried the following code:

```
files = [i.split('.csv', 1)[0] for i in files]
```

I got

```
list= ['/xyz/abc/def/123621912',
 '/xyz/abc/def/1662828716',
 '/xyz/abc/def/1111111111',
 '/xyz/abc/def/7272718119',
 '/xyz/abc/def/92881991911',
 '/xyz/abc/def/6627181911',
 '/xyz/abc/def/2717178192']
```

I couldn't proceed further.

Comment: "I couldn't proceed further" just split again by `/`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: removing characters except digits from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450897/python-removing-characters-except-digits-from-string)

Answer (score 0):

Your code was close, though I would probably split on the slashes instead of the .csv, select the last element of the list that split() returns, and just remove the .csv from that.

`int_list = [path.split('/')[-1].replace('.csv', '') for path in list]`

Answer (score 0):

With regexp (note, don't use `list` as variable name, it shadows built-in function):

```
lst= ['/xyz/abc/def/123621912.csv',
 '/xyz/abc/def/1662828716.csv',
 '/xyz/abc/def/1111111111.csv',
 '/xyz/abc/def/7272718119.csv',
 '/xyz/abc/def/92881991911.csv',
 '/xyz/abc/def/66271819112.csv',
 '/xyz/abc/def/2717178192.csv']

import re
from pprint import pprint

pprint([re.findall(r'(\d+)\.', l)[0] for l in lst])
```

Prints:

```
['123621912',
 '1662828716',
 '1111111111',
 '7272718119',
 '92881991911',
 '66271819112',
 '2717178192']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numList = []

for i in range(len(listA)):
    x = listA[i].split('def/', 1)
    x = x[1].split('.', 1)
    numList.append(x[0])
```

Output:

```
['123621912',
 '1662828716',
 '1111111111',
 '7272718119',
 '92881991911',
 '66271819112',
 '2717178192']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', '\n'.join(lst))
['123621912', '1662828716', '1111111111', '7272718119', '92881991911', '66271819112', '2717178192']
```

By the way, avoid naming your as `list` as it contradicts with the builtin

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want achieve

```
lst= ['123621912','1662828716','1111111111','7272718119','92881991911','66271819112','2717178192']
```

Try with [Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

For example:

```
lst2=[]
for entry in list:
  list2.append(re.search("\d+",entry).group(0)
```

Maybe it's not perfect but it works.