# How to pass value of loop's index in quotation marks

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.7. How does you use the index of a loop inside quotation marks? This appears in a option. I have tried putting index in quote() and after % and also format but it is not working.

```
      for x in range(3,82,7):
          for y in range(10,95,7):
              worksheet.merge_range("A{}".format(x)":A{}".format(y), "", merge_format)
```

I want the output as

```
worksheet.merge_range('A3:A10', 'Merged Range', merge_format)
worksheet.merge_range('A10:A17', 'Merged Range', merge_format)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you want to remove all the non-digit numbers? This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450897/python-removing-characters-except-digits-from-string

Comment: If you're using the "range" function, the index is just x or y. If you want it to have quotation marks around it, make it `"\"{}\"".format(str(x))`

Answer (score 0):

This would be

```
"A{}:A{}".format(x, y)
```

Instead of making two format strings and trying to join them, make a single format string that accepts both inputs.

It also looks like you want to iterate through those two loops in parallel, for which you would need to use `zip`:

```
for x, y in zip(range(3,82,7), range(10,95,7)):
    worksheet.merge_range("A{}:A{}".format(x, y), 'Merged Range', merge_format)
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the formats in one place after the quotes.

```
 "A{}:A{}".format(x, y),
```