# How to check if a string contains letters?

Tags: python, string, split, numbers, letter

I have a numerical string which sometimes it contains letters. I must delete letters and everything after that from my input string.
I have tried:

```
import re
b = re.split('[a-z]|[A-Z]', a)
b = b[0]
```

But this returns error whenever the string doesn't contain letters.

Do I need to check if `a` contains letters before trying to split at their point?

**How can I check that**?

Two examples:

```
a = '1234'
```

and

```
a = '1234h'
```

I want to have `b = '1234'` after both

---

Another example:
I want `a= '4/200, 3500/ 500 h3m'` or `a= '4/200, 3500/ 500h3m'` to
return something like:

```
b= ['4', '200', '3500', '500']
```

Comment: Why do you have a one-element list containing a string, rather than just a string?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450897/remove-characters-except-digits-from-string-using-python) out ?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Anyway, you want `re.sub` and the pattern should match a letter followed by any amount of other characters (as much as possible), and the replacement should be the empty string.

Comment: if OP is indeed using a list with a single string in it, that is throwing the error, since re will show the following error then: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object. Iterate over the list or don't use a list at all

Comment: @Cool Cloud: Thank you. But I need to delete even all the digits after occurrence of any letters (if any letter exist). The link you sent, deletes all letters and keeps all digits.

Comment: @ alaniwi : You right, I checked. The [ ] s were added after my tests and computations for splitting. I omitted [ ] from the input. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
match = re.search('^[\d]+', '1234h')
if match:
    print(match.group(0))
```

It will return **'1234'** for '1234' and '1234h'.
It find series of digits after starting and ignores after letter.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ['1234abc' , '5278', 'abc58586']

def range_sanitizer(s, lower_bound, upper_bound):
    return ''.join([x for x in s if lower_bound < x < upper_bound])

def remove_non_digits(s):
    return range_sanitizer(s, '0', '9')

def sanitize_list(list, sanitizer=remove_non_digits):
    return [sanitizer(item) for item in list]

if '__main__' == __name__:
    sanitized_list=sanitize_list(list)

    # ['1234', '5278', '58586']
    print(sanitized_list)
```