# Is there a way to remove all characters except letters in a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I call a function that returns code with all kinds of characters ranging from ( to ", and , and numbers.

Is there an elegant way to remove all of these so I end up with nothing but letters?

Comment: Hey Take a look at this link someone a similar Question! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851791/removing-numbers-from-string

Comment: Why was my comment removed? I saw people like Jon Skeet asking about similar things here which is valid.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754587 for *general-purpose* removal (everything not matching a whitelist); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450897 for digits only.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Given

```
s = '@#24A-09=wes()&8973o**_##me'  # contains letters 'Awesome'
```

You can filter out non-alpha characters with a generator expression:

```
result = ''.join(c for c in s if c.isalpha())
```

Or filter with `filter`:

```
result = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, s))
```

Or you can substitute non-alpha  with blanks using `re.sub`:

```
import re
result = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z]', '', s)
```

Comment: Wow very slick. I really like when python has elegant solutions like this.

Comment: Note that `isalpha` only counts a-z as letters, not e.g. å, ä, ö, ø, ñ, é or à

Comment: The fastest approach is second one (`filter`). Approximately 2x times than others.
First and third variants are almost equal, but `re` slightly slower.

Answer (score 6):

A solution using RegExes is quite easy here:

```
import re
newstring = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z]+", "", string)
```

Where `string` is your string and `newstring` is the string without characters that are not alphabetic. What this does is replace every character that is not a letter by an empty string, thereby removing it. Note however that a RegEx may be slightly overkill here.

A more functional approach would be:

```
newstring = "".join(filter(str.isalpha, string))
```

Unfortunately you can't just call `str`on a `filter`object to turn it into a string, that would look much nicer...
Going the pythonic way it would be

```
newstring = "".join(c for c in string if c.isalpha())
```

Comment: It should be `re.sub`, `re.replace` doesn't exists.

Comment: You are so right, I actually just looked that up, because I wasn't sure about the Python library, but ended up typing the wrong name anyway...

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mention you want only *english* letters, here's an international solution:

```
import unicodedata

str = u"hello, ѱϘяԼϷ!"
print ''.join(c for c in str if unicodedata.category(c).startswith('L'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one, using [`string.ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters)

```
>>> import string
>>> "".join(x for x in s if x in string.ascii_letters)
```

`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "';''';;';1123123!@#!@#!#!$!sd         sds2312313~~\"~s__"
>>> re.sub("[\W\d_]", "", string)
'sdsdss'
```

Comment: This leaves underscores.

Comment: Oh! yes it was leaving underscores. Edited the answer to remove underscores too.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I use this for myself in this kind of situations

Sorry, if it's outdated :)

```
string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!"
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

def letters_only(source):
    result = ""
    for i in source.lower():
        if i in alphabet:
            result += i
    return result

print(letters_only(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '@#24A-09=wes()&8973o**_##me'

print(filter(str.isalpha, s))

# Awesome
```

About return value of `filter`:

```
filter(function or None, sequence) -> list, tuple, or string
```