# How to check if a string contains only characters from a given set in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.5

I have a a user-inputted polynomial and I only want to use it if it only has characters in the string `1234567890^-+x`.

How can I check if it does or not without using external packages? I only want to use built-in Python 2.5 functions.

I am writing a program that runs on any Mac without needing external packages.

Answer (score 18):

Here are some odd ;-) ways to do it:

```
good = set('1234567890^-+x')

if set(input_string) <= good:
    # it's good
else:
    # it's bad
```

or

```
if input_string.strip('1234567890^-+x'):
    # it's bad!
else:
    # it's good
```

Comment: I love the set subset approach :-) Care to take a `timeit` potshot at it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, not a chance - there are sooooo many ways to do this I don't want to spend half an hour organizing them all ;-)

Comment: @user2357112, just because I can never remember what `.issuperset()` does, exactly, without looking it up :-(  But I understand `<=` at once, and as Martijn says, they're the same thing in the end.  `.issuperset()` is likely slower due to the method lookup expense.

Comment: `issuperset()` is simply the inverse of `issubset()`; the `>=` to your `<=`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, sure, but with the method spellings I can never remember **which one** is `<=` and which `>=` without looking it up.  So I avoid them.  `<=` and `>=` are obvious to me.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `issuperset` would... wait, apparently it doesn't short-circuit. I thought it would do the test without building a set from the `input_string`, but when I tried `{0}.issuperset(xrange(1000000000))` a few seconds ago, it started eating memory in a way that seems to indicate it turns the input into a set. I guess there's no performance advantage.

Answer (score 10):

Use a regular expression:

```
import re

if re.match('^[-0-9^+x]*$', text):
    # Valid input
```

The `re` module comes with Python 2.5, and is your fastest option.

Demo:

```
>>> re.match('^[-0-9^+x]*$', '1x2^4-2')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10f0b6780>
```

Answer (score 4):

1. You can convert the valid chars to a `set`, as sets offer faster lookup
2. Then you can use [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function like this

   ```
   valid_chars = set("1234567890^-+x")  # Converting to a set
   if all(char in valid_chars for char in input_string):
       # Do stuff if input is valid
   ```
3. We can convert the input string also a set and check if all characters in the inputstring is in the valid list.

   ```
   valid_chars = set("1234567890^-+x")  # Converting to a set
   if set(input_string).issubset(valid_chars):
       # Do stuff if input is valid
   ```

Comment: Sets have an `issuperset` method for this.

Comment: @user2357112 Please check my answer now, I have used `issubset`

Comment: That's not the syntax for turning a string into a set; you want `set("1234567890^-+x")`. (Why did I see the other thing first?)

Comment: @user2357112 That's called set comprehension.

Comment: No, it's not. It's a set literal with 1 element.

Comment: @TimPeters Ya, he is correct :) I always get confused with that notation :(

Answer (score 4):

What about just convert both the string into set and checking `input_set is subset of good_set` as below:

```
>>> good_set = set('1234567890^-+x')
>>> input_set1 = set('xajfb123')
>>> input_set2 = set('122-32+x')
>>> input_set1.issubset(good_set)
False
>>> input_set2.issubset(good_set)
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do it, now using [`string.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate):

```
>>> import string
>>> all_chars = string.maketrans('', '')
>>> has_only = lambda s, valid_chars: not s.translate(all_chars, valid_chars)
>>> has_only("abc", "1234567890^-+x.")
False
>>> has_only("x^2", "1234567890^-+x.")
True
```

It is not the most readable way. It should be one of the fastest *if* you need it.

Comment: You can pass as `None` as the first argument to `translate()` instead.

Comment: Does anyone even have a Python 2.5 anymore to check?  LOL ;-)  It works in all *current* Pythons :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
whitelist = '1234567890^-+x'

str = 'x^2+2x+1'
min([ch in whitelist for ch in str])
True


str='x**2 + 1' 
min([ch in whitelist for ch in str])
False
```

Comment: `min()` is hardly the best function for this task.

Comment: Agree that all would be the best choice. Hangover from other languages.