# How to validate user input in python

Tags: python, string, validation, user-input

I am brand new to python and I am trying to figure out how to validate user input. I want to ask the user to submit a DNA sequence and want to validate that it is a DNA sequence. Acceptable inputs can have upper or lowercase ATCGs and spaces and I'm not sure exactly how to do it.

So far I can ask for the input but not verify it.

```
import sys
Var1 = raw_input("Enter Sequence 1:")
```

I then want to do something like:

```
if Var1 != ATCG (somehow put 'characters that match ATCG or space)
    print "Please input valid DNA sequence"
    sys.exit() (to have it close the program)
```

Any help? I feel like this should be rather simple but I don't know how to specify that it can be any ATCG, atcg or space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`all`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), [`str.lower`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower), and a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
if not all(x in "agct " for x in Var1.lower()):
    print "Please input valid DNA sequence"
    sys.exit(1)
```

In the above code, the last two lines will be run if any character in `Var1` is not one of the following:

```
"A", "T", "C", "G", " ", "a", "t", "c", "g"
```

Comment: As a best practice, [sys.exit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) should probably have a non-zero exit code argument since the program didn't succeed.

Comment: @jpmc26 - Good point.  I updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

Also (similar to [In Python, how to check if a string only contains certain characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323364/in-python-how-to-check-if-a-string-only-contains-certain-characters)):

```
>>> import re
>>> def special_match(strg, search=re.compile(r'[^atcgATCG\s]').search):
...   return bool(search(strg))
>>> if (special_match("atcF")):
...   print "Invalid input"
...
>>> Invalid input
```