# Deleting consonants from a string in Python

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, python-idle

Here is my code. I'm not exactly sure if I need a counter for this to work. The answer should be `'iiii'`.

```
def eliminate_consonants(x):
        vowels= ['a','e','i','o','u']
        vowels_found = 0
        for char in x:
            if char == vowels:
                print(char)

eliminate_consonants('mississippi')
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Correcting your code

The line `if char == vowels:` is wrong. It has to be `if char in vowels:`. This is because you need to check if that particular character is present in the list of vowels. Apart from that you need to `print(char,end = '')` (in python3) to print the output as `iiii` all in one line.

The final program will be like

```
def eliminate_consonants(x):
        vowels= ['a','e','i','o','u']
        for char in x:
            if char in vowels:
                print(char,end = "")

eliminate_consonants('mississippi')
```

And the output will be

```
iiii
```

---

### Other ways include

- ***Using `in` a string***

  ```
  def eliminate_consonants(x):
      for char in x:
          if char in 'aeiou':
              print(char,end = "")
  ```

  As simple as it looks, the statement `if char in 'aeiou'` checks if `char` is present in the string `aeiou`.
- ***[A list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)***

  ```
   ''.join([c for c in x if c in 'aeiou'])
  ```

  This list comprehension will return a list that will contain the characters only if the character is in `aeiou`
- ***[A generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)***

  ```
  ''.join(c for c in x if c in 'aeiou')
  ```

  This gen exp will return a generator than will return the characters only if the character is in `aeiou`
- ***[Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)***

  You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to discover only the vowels in your string. The code

  ```
  re.findall(r'[aeiou]',"mississippi")
  ```

  will return a list of vowels found in the string i.e. `['i', 'i', 'i', 'i']`. So now we can use `str.join` and then use

  ```
  ''.join(re.findall(r'[aeiou]',"mississippi"))
  ```
- ***[`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and [`maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)***

  For this technique you will need to store a map which matches each of the non vowels to a `None` type. For this you can use [`string.ascii_lowecase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase). The code to make the map is

  ```
  str.maketrans({i:None for i in string.ascii_lowercase if i not in "aeiou"})
  ```

  this will return the mapping. Do store it in a variable (here `m` for map)

  ```
  "mississippi".translate(m)
  ```

  This will remove all the non `aeiou` characters from the string.
- ***Using [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys)***

  You can use `dict.fromkeys` along with [`sys.maxunicode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxunicode). But remember to `import sys` first!

  ```
  dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(sys.maxunicode+1) if chr(i) not in 'aeiou')
  ```

  and now use `str.translate`.

  ```
  'mississippi'.translate(m)
  ```
- ***Using [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytearray)***

  As mentioned by [J.F.Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/j-f-sebastian) in the [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998052/print-vowels-in-string-python/29998062?noredirect=1#comment50843538_29998062), you can create a bytearray of lower case consonants by using

  ```
  non_vowels = bytearray(set(range(0x100)) - set(b'aeiou'))
  ```

  Using this we can translate the word ,

  ```
  'mississippi'.encode('ascii', 'ignore').translate(None, non_vowels)
  ```

  which will return `b'iiii'`. This can easily be converted to `str` by using `decode` i.e. `b'iiii'.decode("ascii")`.
- ***Using [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes)***

  `bytes` returns an bytes object and is the immutable version of `bytearray`. (**It is Python 3 specific**)

  ```
  non_vowels = bytes(set(range(0x100)) - set(b'aeiou'))
  ```

  Using this we can translate the word ,

  ```
  'mississippi'.encode('ascii', 'ignore').translate(None, non_vowels)
  ```

  which will return `b'iiii'`. This can easily be converted to `str` by using `decode` i.e. `b'iiii'.decode("ascii")`.

---

### Timing comparison

### Python 3

```
python3 -m timeit -s "text = 'mississippi'*100; non_vowels = bytes(set(range(0x100)) - set(b'aeiou'))" "text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').translate(None, non_vowels).decode('ascii')"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.88 usec per loop
python3 -m timeit -s "text = 'mississippi'*100; non_vowels = bytearray(set(range(0x100)) - set(b'aeiou'))" "text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').translate(None, non_vowels).decode('ascii')"
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.06 usec per loop
python3 -m timeit -s "text = 'mississippi'*100;d=dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(127) if chr(i) not in 'aeiou')" "text.translate(d)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 71.3 usec per loop
python3 -m timeit -s "import string; import sys; text='mississippi'*100; m = dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(sys.maxunicode+1) if chr(i) not in 'aeiou')" "text.translate(m)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 71.6 usec per loop
python3 -m timeit -s "text = 'mississippi'*100" "''.join(c for c in text if c in 'aeiou')"
10000 loops, best of 3: 60.1 usec per loop
python3 -m timeit -s "text = 'mississippi'*100" "''.join([c for c in text if c in 'aeiou'])"
10000 loops, best of 3: 53.2 usec per loop
python3 -m timeit -s "import re;text = 'mississippi'*100; p=re.compile(r'[aeiou]')" "''.join(p.findall(text))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 57 usec per loop
```

The timings in sorted order

```
translate (bytes)    |  2.88
translate (bytearray)|  3.06
List Comprehension   | 53.2
Regular expressions  | 57.0
Generator exp        | 60.1
dict.fromkeys        | 71.3
translate (unicode)  | 71.6
```

As you can see the final method using `bytes` is the fastest.

---

### Python 3.5

```
python3.5 -m timeit -s "text = 'mississippi'*100; non_vowels = bytes(set(range(0x100)) - set(b'aeiou'))" "text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').translate(None, non_vowels).decode('ascii')"
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.17 usec per loop
python3.5 -m timeit -s "text = 'mississippi'*100; non_vowels = bytearray(set(range(0x100)) - set(b'aeiou'))" "text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').translate(None, non_vowels).decode('ascii')"
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.21 usec per loop
python3.5 -m timeit -s "text = 'mississippi'*100;d=dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(127) if chr(i) not in 'aeiou')" "text.translate(d)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.39 usec per loop
python3.5 -m timeit -s "import string; import sys; text='mississippi'*100; m = dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(sys.maxunicode+1) if chr(i) not in 'aeiou')" "text.translate(m)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.33 usec per loop
python3.5 -m timeit -s "text = 'mississippi'*100" "''.join(c for c in text if c in 'aeiou')"
10000 loops, best of 3: 97.1 usec per loop
python3.5 -m timeit -s "text = 'mississippi'*100" "''.join([c for c in text if c in 'aeiou'])"
10000 loops, best of 3: 86.6 usec per loop
python3.5 -m timeit -s "import re;text = 'mississippi'*100; p=re.compile(r'[aeiou]')" "''.join(p.findall(text))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 74.3 usec per loop
```

The timings in sorted order

```
translate (unicode)  |  2.33
dict.fromkeys        |  2.39
translate (bytes)    |  4.17
translate (bytearray)|  4.21
List Comprehension   | 86.6
Regular expressions  | 74.3
Generator exp        | 97.1
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Appreciate the fast response. :) :)

Comment: Can you pls let me know how to print the output all in one line in Python 2.7 as this: `print(char,end = "")` only seems to works in Paython 3. Thanks.

Comment: @JoeR `print char,` in py2 (Note the trailing comma)

Comment: What does `vowels_found = 0` mean ?

Comment: If you need speed; work with bytes and call `bytestring.translate(None, non_vowels)`

Comment: `.translate()` for Unicode string is very slow (compared to `bytes` version). See [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/265960/4279)

Comment: @BhargavRao: bytes-version is 10x faster than genexpr: `70.3`us vs. `4.75`us: `(b'mississippi'*100).translate(None, non_vowels)` where `non_vowels = bytearray(set(range(0x100)) - set(b'aeiou'))`. Or if input is Unicode: `text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').translate(None, non_vowels)` (it is also 10x faster than `''.join([c for c in text if c in 'aeiou'])`) where `text = 'mississippi'*100`.

Comment: 1. `str.maketrans` and `dict.fromkeys` could be moved to the setup too. 2. To support arbitrary input, you should use `range(sys.maxunicode+1)` instead of `range(127)` there 3. On CPython: `''.join([...])` (listcomp) is faster than `''.join(...)` (genexpr).

Comment: @BhargavRao: What is your OS, Python version? I don't remember seeing that `''.join(genexpr)` being faster than `''.join(listcomp)`. [ideone confirms it](http://ideone.com/veVaH8).

Comment: note: I've used `bytearray()` rather than `bytes()` to make the code being able to run on both Python 2 and 3 (from the same source)

Comment: (it is not the end ;)) Note: [Python 3.5 greatly improves `dict.fromkeys` unicode `.translate()` case](http://bugs.python.org/issue21118) (same performance as `bytes` case for the input in the answer).

Comment: Yep, certainly. Let's improve the answer to contain 3.5 specs too. But for that I have to read WNIP3.5 before :/. Actually @J.F. I'm waiting for my current project to get over and completely remove 3.4. and move over to 3.5.

Comment: @J.F. Added the Python3.5 results. The table has just overturned.

Comment: As the time complexity of list search is O(n) while set search is O(1), among the "simple" solutions I would rather use the search within a set: wowels_s = set(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']) followed by if char in wovels_s etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can try pythonic way like this,

```
In [1]: s = 'mississippi'
In [3]: [char for char in s if char in 'aeiou']
Out[3]: ['i', 'i', 'i', 'i']
```

Function;

```
In [4]: def eliminate_consonants(x):
   ...:     return ''.join(char for char in x if char in 'aeiou')
   ...: 

In [5]: print(eliminate_consonants('mississippi'))
iiii
```

Comment: Errr! I rather prefer `return ''.join([char for char in x if char in 'aeiou'])`. Direct and easy to understand :)

Comment: @BhargavRao Building your intermediate list is both unnecessary and costly. You should remove those `[]`. Another alternative is `''.join(filter('aeiou'.__contains__, s))`. I tested a 10 million lowercase letters string, Bhargav's way took 2.16 seconds, mine took 1.47 seconds, Bhargav's without creating that intermediate list took 1.25 seconds.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thanks Buddy for that info. I will update [my](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29998062/4099593) answer.

Comment: @BhargavRao The update there was good as well, but what I meant was your comment here. Just use `''.join(char ... 'aeiou')` without those `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

`==` tests for equality. You are looking to see if any of the characters exist in the string that are in your list 'vowels'. To do that, you can simply use `in` such as below.

Additionally, I see you have a 'vowels_found' variable but are not utilizing it. Below one example how you can solve this:

```
def eliminate_consonants(x):
    vowels= ['a','e','i','o','u']
    vowels_found = 0
    for char in x:
        if char in vowels:
            print(char)
            vowels_found += 1

    print "There are", vowels_found, "vowels in", x

eliminate_consonants('mississippi')
```

Your output would then be:

```
i
i
i
i
There are 4 vowels in mississippi
```

Comment: At best, this is a comment, not an answer.