# In Python how to whitelist certain characters in a filename?

Tags: python, regex, string

To secure uploaded image names, I'd like to strip out image's filenames from anything but `string.ascii_letters` , `string.digits`, dot and (one) whitespace.

So I'm wondering what is the best method to check a text against other characters?

Comment: so (one) whitespace is mandatory in a filename?

Comment: Do have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998052/deleting-consonants-from-a-string-in-python/29998062#29998062) which has around 8 different ways of checking and removing certain characters.

Comment: @PruthviRaj, well just to avoid messy names, yes.

Comment: @BhargavRao no. but it is definitely useful. Thanks!

Comment: @Paulrx Yep. I just added the link to show you a few ways. It certainly does not answer your question. Glad you found it useful. Cheers.

Comment: What are you trying to secure against? Why not randomly generate the file names, and possibly store a mapping of real names to file paths in your database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re
import os
s = 'asodgnasAIDID12313%*(@&(!$ 1231'
result = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z\d\. ]|( ){2,}','',s )
if result =='' or os.path.splitext(result)[0].isspace():
    print "not a valid name"
else:
    print "valid name"
```

EDIT:

changed it so it will also whitelist only one whitespace + added import re

Comment: Very concise. To complete the answer just add `import re` . Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I just found a caveat. If you choos a utf8 filename with several white spaces, the final name will be something like `'    '` which is not desireable. Any ideas about this?

Comment: if i understand you correctly than it needs to be empty, if so than now this should work ( i replaced th (  )+ double space with + to ( ){2,} be atleast to space so if there is an uneven number of spaces this should still work)

Comment: the problem with this solution is that is tha if you enter non-ascii filenames, like `s = '些 些.jpg'` the result will be `' .jpg'` which is not good.

Comment: well this is a problem with your requirement as this is a single space witch answers the rules you specify, but in this case i would have added a special case to handle this

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's what you need but give it a try:

```
import sys, os

fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext('image  11%%22.jpg')
fileExtension = fileExtension.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
fileName = fileName.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
if fileExtension[1:] in ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'tga']:
    fileName = ''.join(e for e in fileName if e.isalnum())
    print fileName+fileExtension
    #image1122.jpg
else:
    print "Extension not supported"
```

---

```
isalnum()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum

Comment: Well it returns `.jpg` when the filename is not ascii.

Comment: You can `ascii` encode `fileExtension` and `fileName` with `fileExtension.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`, before checking it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use regex for this. The only tricky requirement is the single space, but that can be done, too.

```
import string

whitelist = set(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
good_filename = "herearesomelettersand123numbers andonespace"
bad_filename = "symbols&#! and more than one space"

def strip_filename(fname, whitelist):
    """Strips a filename

    Removes any character from string `fname` and removes all but one
    whitespace.
    """

    whitelist.add(" ")

    stripped = ''.join([ch for ch in fname if ch in whitelist])
    split = stripped.split()
    result = " ".join([split[0], ''.join(split[1:])])
    return result
```

Then call it with:

```
good_sanitized = strip_filename(good_filename, whitelist)
bad_sanitized = strip_filename(bad_filename, whitelist)
print(good_sanitized)
# 'herearesomelettersand123numbers andonespace'
print(bad_sanitized)
# 'symbols andmorethanonespace'
```

Comment: please remove duplicated answer

Comment: Yes to both. Net's acting up a bit and I had to refresh a POST I think. Deleted the dupe.

Comment: Well this fails for non-ascii file names. Take `'些 些.jpg'`. Your method returns `'jpg '`.