# Why is str.translate much faster in Python 3.5 compared to Python 3.4?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-internals, python-3.5

I was trying to remove unwanted characters from a given string using `text.translate()` in Python 3.4.

The minimal code is:

```
import sys 
s = 'abcde12345@#@$#%$'
mapper = dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if chr(i) in '@#$')
print(s.translate(mapper))
```

It works as expected. However the same program when executed in Python 3.4 and Python 3.5 gives a large difference.

The code to calculate timings is

```
python3 -m timeit -s "import sys;s = 'abcde12345@#@$#%$'*1000 ; mapper = dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if chr(i) in '@#$'); "   "s.translate(mapper)"
```

The Python 3.4 program takes ***1.3ms*** whereas the same program in Python 3.5 takes only ***26.4μs***.

What has improved in Python 3.5 that makes it faster compared to Python 3.4?

Comment: While we're talking about performance, wouldn't it be better to generate your mapper like this: `dict.fromkeys(ord(c) for c in '@#$')`?

Comment: @ThomasK I found out that this made a significant difference. Yep your way is better.

Comment: Did you mean 50x faster?

Comment: @assylias I did 1300 - 26.4 and then divided by 1300. I got nearly 95%, so I wrote :) It is actually more than 50x faster... But is my calculation wrong? I'm bit weak in math. I'll learn math soon. :)

Comment: you should do it the way round: 26 / 1300 = 2% so the faster version takes only 2% of the time taken by the slower version => it is 50x faster.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

**TL;DR - [ISSUE 21118](http://bugs.python.org/issue21118)**

---

**The long Story**

Josh Rosenberg found out that the `str.translate()` function is very slow compared to the `bytes.translate`, he raised an [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue21118), stating that:

> In Python 3, `str.translate()` is usually a performance pessimization, not optimization.

#### Why was `str.translate()` slow?

The main reason for `str.translate()` to be very slow was that the lookup used to be in a Python dictionary.

The usage of `maketrans` made this problem worse. The similar approach using [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes) builds a C array of 256 items to fast table lookup. Hence the usage of higher level Python `dict` makes the `str.translate()` in Python 3.4 very slow.

#### What happened now?

The first approach was to add a small patch, [translate_writer](http://bugs.python.org/file34691/translate_writer.patch), However the speed increase was not that pleasing. Soon another patch [fast_translate](http://bugs.python.org/file34731/fast_translate.patch) was tested and it yielded very nice results of up to 55% speedup.

The main change as can be seen from the file is that the Python dictionary lookup is changed into a C level lookup.

The speeds now are almost the same as `bytes`

```
                                unpatched           patched

str.translate                   4.55125927699919    0.7898181750006188
str.translate from bytes trans  1.8910855210015143  0.779950579000797
```

---

A small note here is that the performance enhancement is only prominent in ASCII strings.

As J.F.Sebastian mentions in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287893/why-is-str-translate-so-fast-in-python-3-5-compared-to-python-3-4-1/34287999?noredirect=1#comment56339043_34287999) below, Before 3.5, translate used to work in the same way for both ASCII and non-ASCII cases. However from 3.5  ASCII case is much faster.

Earlier ASCII vs non-ascii used to be almost same, however now we can see a great change in the performance.

It can be an improvement from 71.6μs to 2.33μs as seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998052/deleting-consonants-from-a-string-in-python/29998062#29998062).

The following code demonstrates this

```
python3.5 -m timeit -s "text = 'mJssissippi'*100; d=dict(J='i')" "text.translate(d)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.3 usec per loop
python3.5 -m timeit -s "text = 'm\U0001F602ssissippi'*100; d={'\U0001F602': 'i'}" "text.translate(d)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 117 usec per loop

python3 -m timeit -s "text = 'm\U0001F602ssissippi'*100; d={'\U0001F602': 'i'}" "text.translate(d)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 91.2 usec per loop
python3 -m timeit -s "text = 'mJssissippi'*100; d=dict(J='i')" "text.translate(d)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 101 usec per loop
```

Tabulation of the results:

```
         Python 3.4    Python 3.5  
Ascii     91.2          2.3 
Unicode   101           117
```

Comment: This is one of the commits: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/87056cb061ede3c30952c43970b41cafa112d3bf

Comment: note: ascii vs. non-ascii case may differ significantly in performance. It is not about `55`%: as [your answer shows, the speed up can be `1000`s%](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29998062/4279).

Comment: compare: `python3.5 -m timeit -s "text = 'mJssissippi'*100; d=dict(J='i')" "text.translate(d)"` (ascii) vs. `python3.5 -m timeit -s "text = 'm\U0001F602ssissippi'*100; d={'\U0001F602': 'i'}" "text.translate(d)"` (non-ascii). The latter is much (10x) slower.

Comment: @J.F. Oh, I understood it now. I ran your code for both 3.4 and 3.5. I am getting Py3.4 faster for non-ascii stuff. Is it by coincidence? The results http://dpaste.com/15FKSDQ

Comment: Before 3.5, both ascii and non-ascii cases are probably the same for Unicode `.translate()` i.e.,  ascii case is much faster in Python 3.5 only (you don't need `bytes.translate()` for performance there).

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that `bytes.translate()` is suitable for a non-ascii case e.g., `'\U0001F602'` is a multi-byte sequence (in most encodings) and therefore you can't map it using `bytes.translate()` (it is not the only reason but it is enough). Note: [the initial case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998052/deleting-consonants-from-a-string-in-python/29998062#comment50841257_29998062)  is ascii-only.

Comment: To my ear 1000% improvement suggests the code is not only 9 times as fast but actually runs backward in time and finishes before it starts :-P Just kidding, of course, but I do see it as somewhat unclear what 1000% improvement means. If you find yourself making another edit anyway, I'd recommend altering that wording. (The timing results you posted are what I'd consider a roughly 90% improvement: the improved version takes (100%-90%)=10% as long as the original.)

Comment: @DavidZ I am really confused with the calculations! :P Can you please tell me the percentage.. From 91.2 to 2.3? (I am poor in math :( )

Comment: @BhargavRao oh, sure. For percent changes, **always divide by the _original_ value**, not the new one. In this case, (91.2 - 2.3) / 91.2 x 100% = 97.5% improvement.

Comment: @DavidZ Thanks a lot. I was dividing by the wrong value (the latter). o wonder I got 3000% improvement when the devs claimed 55%.... Thanks again. :)

Comment: @DavidZ: 97.5% is not human-readable -- *there are multiple formulas possible*. 1000s% is from my comment above (Python 3.5 is the baseline 100%). The purpose is to communicate **the order of magnitude** (tens of times -- thousands  percents unlike fifty percents that were in the answer before -- otherwise I wouldn't use percents at all here). The point is unicode .translate() was dog-slow in the ascii case before Python 3.5. Also, 97.5% *promises too much* (unlike 1000s%) -- benchmarking is a tricky endeavor to get right if we stop talking about order of magnitudes numbers.

Comment: @J.F. I believe in your last line. I think the important thing is to get the main point that .translate() has been improved. I have for the present removed the comparisons. Thanks a lot.