# How do i remove all character besides digits and "," from unicode string in python?

Tags: python, xpath, unicode, scrapy

I'm writing small crawler using scrapy.
One of XPath's is containing price followed by "zł" (polish currency mark) the problem is it's obfuscated by new line characters, spaces and non breaking spaces.
so when I do :

```
sel.xpath("div/div/span/span/text()[normalize-space(.)]").extract()
```

I get:

```
[u'\n            1\xa0740,00 z\u0142\n            \n            \n                ']
```

Which I want to change to

```
[u'1740,00']
```

or simply into float variable.
What is the /best/simplest/fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `re.findall` to extract the characters from the string:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = u'\n            1\xa0740,00 z\u0142\n            \n            \n            '
>>> L = re.findall(r'[\d,]', s)
>>> "".join(L)
'1740,00'
```

Comment: i got it going like that


    `raw_price = sel.xpath("div/div/span/span/text()").extract()

    item['cena']= raw_price[0].strip()`

Comment: @Lord_JABA: `.strip()` only removes leading and trailing whitespace. Perhaps, the most flexible solution here is using a regular expression.

Comment: But these characters doesn't come in the final saving if we use `.strip()`

Comment: @Nikhil:  `s.strip()` will give you `'1\xa0740,00 zł'` which is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @eugeney I encounter these characters a lot while scraping but when I insert into my db say `mongo` why I get the actual data or even if I print on a csv may be I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested only in ascii digits then [the fastest method is to use `bytes.translate()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29998052/4279):

```
import string

keep = string.digits.encode() + b',' # characters to keep
delete = bytearray(set(range(0x100)) - set(bytearray(keep))) # to delete
result = unicode_string.encode('ascii', 'ignore').translate(None, delete).decode()
```

You could write it more succinctly using Unicode `.translate()`:

```
import string
import sys

keep = set(map(ord, string.digits + ',')) # characters to keep
table = dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(sys.maxunicode + 1) if i not in keep)
result = unicode_string.translate(table)
```

The result is the same but [before Python 3.5, it is always dog-slow (the situation is better in Python 3.5 for ascii-only case)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34287893/4279).