# Python3 Fast Way To Find If Any Elements In Collections Are Substring Of String

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, big-o, string-algorithm

If I have a `collection of strings` is there a data structure or function that could improve the speed of checking if any of the elements of the collections are `substrings` on my main string?

Right now I'm looping through my array of strings and using the `in` operator. Is there a faster way?

```
import timing

## string match in first do_not_scan
## 0:00:00.029332

## string not in do_not_scan
## 0:00:00.035179
def check_if_substring():
    for x in do_not_scan:
        if x in string:
            return True
    return False

## string match in first do_not_scan
## 0:00:00.046530

## string not in do_not_scan
## 0:00:00.067439
def index_of():
    for x in do_not_scan:
        try:
            string.index(x)
            return True
        except:
            return False

## string match in first do_not_scan
## 0:00:00.047654

## string not in do_not_scan
## 0:00:00.070596
def find_def():
    for x in do_not_scan:
        if string.find(x) != -1:
            return True
    return False

string = '/usr/documents/apps/components/login'
do_not_scan = ['node_modules','bower_components']

for x in range(100000):
    find_def()
    index_of()
    check_if_substring()
```

Comment: Is it possible that you pasted something wrong here. Or is `string = 'a'` just a sample. Because `node_modules` will never be in `string`. With that said, can you use a map. Where the keys are the items of `do_not_scan`. Then the search is O(1)

Comment: just a sample to demonstrate `string` may not contain any elements of `do_not_scan`. I've never used a map before how would you go about doing that?

Comment: Do you want the analog of `grep -l -Ff collections_of_strings main_string`? where `collections_of_strings` file contains a collections of strings (one per line) and `main_string` file contains the main string (as is).

Comment: I will edit, meant is there a better data structure eg. put things in a set instead of an array that would make the search faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no faster built-in way.

If you have large amounts of strings to test for, then you may be better off using a third-party [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) package, as [J.F. Sebastian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35816817/208880) shows.

---

Using the built-in methods, the worst-case scenario is: there is no match, which means you have tested every item in the list and nearly every offset in every item.

Fortunately, the `in` operator is very quick (at least in CPython) and was faster by nearly a factor of three in my tests:

```
0.3364804992452264  # substring()
0.867534976452589   # any_substring()
0.8401796016842127  # find_def()
0.9342398950830102  # index_of()
2.7920695478096604  # re implementation
```

---

Here is the script I used for testing:

```
from timeit import timeit
import re

def substring():
    for x in do_not_scan:
        if x in string:
            return True
    return False

def any_substring():
    return any(x in string for x in do_not_scan)

def find_def():
    for x in do_not_scan:
        if string.find(x) != -1:
            return True
    return False

def index_of():
    for x in do_not_scan:
        try:
            string.index(x)
            return True
        except:
            return False

def re_match():
    for x in do_not_scan:
        if re.search(string, x):
            return True
    return False

string = 'a'
do_not_scan = ['node_modules','bower_components']

print(timeit('substring()', setup='from __main__ import substring'))
print(timeit('any_substring()', setup='from __main__ import any_substring'))
print(timeit('find_def()', setup='from __main__ import find_def'))
print(timeit('index_of()', setup='from __main__ import index_of'))
print(timeit('re_match()', setup='from __main__ import re_match'))
```

Comment: it is incorrect. You can do better than `O(n*m)` e.g., [Aho–Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) is `O(n + m)` in time. [`grep` may use it for fixed strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803016/python3-fast-way-to-find-if-any-elements-in-collections-are-substring-of-string#comment59300275_35803016)

Answer (score 2):

```
def check():
    if any(w in string for w in do_not_scan):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Or simpler:

```
def check():
    return any(w in string for w in do_not_scan)
```

as mentioned by @Two-Bit Alchemist

Comment: string match in first do_not_scan = 0:00:00.085493 |
string not in do_not_scan = 0:00:00.074540

Comment: Simpler: `return any(w in string for w in do_not_scan)`

Comment: `any` is as slow as `find_def` and `index_of`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a large dataset to try:

But maybes something like this will work?

**python3**

```
from builtins import any
import timeit

do_not_scan = ['node_modules', 'bower_components']
string = 'a'


def check_if_substring():
    return any(string in x for x in do_not_scan)


result = timeit.Timer("check_if_substring()", "from __main__ import check_if_substring")
count = 10000
print(result.timeit(count)/count)
```

Or the other way around:

```
def check_if_substring():
    return any(x in string for x in do_not_scan)
```

My results: `6.48119201650843e-07`

Comment: Just curious -- why are you renaming any and why that way?

Comment: It was a copy and past from and old code. Doesn't make sense in this context. Ill fix it

Comment: `any` is as slow as `find_def` and `index_of`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a faster way to perform `found = any(s in main_string for s in collection_of_strings)` e.g., there is [Aho-Corasick_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) that allows to improve `any()`-based `O(n*m*k)` algorithm to `O(n + m*k)` in time operation where `n` is `len(main_string)`, `m` is `len(collections_of_strings)`, and `k` represents individual lengths of the strings in the collection.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import noaho # $ pip install noaho

trie = noaho.NoAho()
for s in collection_of_strings:
    trie.add(s)
found = trie.find_short(main_string)[0] is not None
```

Note: there is no point to measure the time performance on tiny strings such as `string = 'a'` if you are interested in Big-O behavior. Either use a more representative sample for the benchmark or you don't need a faster (asymptotically) algorithm in your case.

Comment: Can you offer any guidance of where the cut-off is to use an Aho-Corasick algorithm over `in`?

Comment: Only your profiler knows. Constant factors depend on the quality of the implementation e.g., [`str.translate()` in Python 3.5+ on ASCII-only input may be 50 times faster than the same code on previous Python 3 versions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34287893/4279).