# How do you replace and reverse a string in python?

Tags: python, string, reverse

This is what I have so far, it is not replacing the C with a G for some reason. Why might this be?

```
DNASeq=raw_input("Enter the DNA sequence here: ")
DNASeq=DNASeq.upper().replace(" ","")

reverse=DNASeq[::-1]

print reverse.replace('A','U').replace('T','A').replace('C','G').replace('G','C')
```

Comment: You're replacing the C with a G, and then replacing (all) Gs with a C. What do you expect? There'll be lots of C in your output, but no G.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you replace `C` with `G` then `G` with `C`. One simple way to prevent you going from one to the other would be to replace `C` with `g`, so it wouldn't then go back to `C`, then uppercase the result:

```
gattaca="GATTACA"
rev = gattaca[::-1]
print rev.replace('A','u').replace('T','a').replace('C','g').replace('G','c').upper()
```

This correctly outputs `UGUAAUC` instead of `UCUAAUC` as your example did.

### UPDATE

The more Pythonic way, though, and avoiding the case-based hack, and being more efficient as the string doesn't need to be scanned five times, and being more obvious as to the purpose, would be:

```
from string import maketrans
transtab = maketrans("ATCG", "UAGC")
print rev.translate(transtab)
```

Comment: Yes, this should have been obvious to me from the beginning! It is also much faster than my dictionary-based method, on python 3.5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287893/why-is-str-translate-faster-in-python-3-5-compared-to-python-3-4

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out already, the problem is that your are replacing ALL Cs with Gs first. I wanted to throw in this approach because I think it would be the most efficient:

```
>>> complement = {'A':'U', 'G':'C', 'C':'G','T':'A'}
>>> seq = "GATTACA"
>>> "".join(complement[c] for c in seq)[::-1]
'UGUAAUC'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done almost correct code.
but here one thing you need to understand is First you replace C with G and again you replace G with C.

> .replace('C','G').replace('G','C')

just remove `.replace('G','C')` from your code and everything works fine.

here is the correct code:

```
DNASeq=raw_input("Enter the DNA sequence here: ")
DNASeq=DNASeq.upper().replace(" ","")

reverse=DNASeq[::-1]

print reverse.replace('A','U').replace('T','A').replace('C','G').replace('G','C')
```