# Check if a string contains only characters from a regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Trying to create a function which with a given a **regular expression which holds all the legal characters**, a string will be checked if it **only** contains those characters.

For example

```
import re
legal_characters = r'[\*\-]' # Matches asterisc and dash characters

def is_legal(test_string):
    if re.match(legal_characters, test_string):
        print("Legal")
    else:
        print("Not legal")

is_legal("***---123")  # should print "Not legal"
is_legal("AbC123")     # should print "Not legal"
is_legal("*-*-*")      # should print "Legal"
```

output:

```
Not legal
Not legal
Not legal
```

I do not really understand why. Could someone please explain?

Comment: tested on python 3.4: all strings are legal; `re` matches the first letter only (`<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>`).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I made a poor choice of a regular expression. Please see modified description..

Comment: TigerhawkT3 is right, this is a duplicate no matter how small the differences are. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323364/in-python-how-to-check-if-a-string-only-contains-certain-characters which holds a more complete answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this reproduces what you want: `^` matches the beginning of the string `$` the end. in between there are repeating `+` characters `\w = [A-Za-z0-9_]`.

```
legal_characters = '^\w+$'
```

**update**

after the modification of your question this is my suggestion:

`^` matches the beginning of the string `$` the end. in between there are repeating `+` elements of `[*-]`:

```
legal_characters = '^[*-]+$'
```

there is no need to escape `*-` with `\`.

as pointed out by **Maroun Maroun** you can leave out the `^` as `match` scans the beginning of the string anyway:

```
legal_characters = '[*-]+$'
```

Comment: `^` is not needed when using `match` since it already attempts to match from the beginning of the string.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: agreed. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import re
legal_characters = r'\w+$' # Matches Unicode word characters
r = re.compile(legal_characters)

def is_legal(test_string):
    if re.match(r, test_string):
        print("Legal")
    else:
        print("Not legal")

is_legal("aaaAA$")  # should print "Not legal"
is_legal("AAAA***") # should print "Not legal"
is_legal("AAABBB")  # should print "Legal"
```

Tested on python 2.7.12.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `re`. Try:

```
legal_characters = '*-'

def is_legal(test_string):
    for s in test_string:
        if s not in legal_characters:
            print("Not legal")
            return
    print("Legal")
```

And the output is:

```
>>> is_legal("***---123")
Not legal
>>> is_legal("AbC123") 
Not legal
>>> is_legal("*-*-*")
Legal
```

Comment: Note that this would include the brackets as allowed characters, which they're not supposed to be. I'd recommend defining `legal_characters = {'*', '-'}`. You could also simplify this to `def is_legal(test_string): return all(c in legal_characters for c in test_string)`.

Comment: Okay thought bracets were legal as well. Yes I like the simplification but I think he wants a function which prints, not returns, if I understood correctly.

Comment: That's probably just to simplify the test calls.

Comment: Okay thank you, I edited it with the simplification propose as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, as I say in my question, I do want to use regular expressions. Among other reasons, with regular expression it will be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
legal_characters = r'[*-]+' # Matches asterisc and dash characters

def is_legal(test_string):
    if re.fullmatch(legal_characters, test_string):
        print("Legal")
    else:
        print("Not legal")
is_legal("***---123")  # should print "Not legal"
is_legal("AbC123")     # should print "Not legal"
is_legal("*-*-*")      # should print "Legal"
```

out:

```
Not legal
Not legal
Legal
```

first:

> Special characters **lose their special meaning** inside sets. For
>   example, `[(+*)]` will match any of the literal characters ’(’, ’+’,
>   ’*’, or ’)’

than:

```
re.fullmatch(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

> If the **whole string** matches the regular expression pattern, return a
>   corresponding match object. Return None if the string does not match
>   the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.