# Inverting a binary string with check on python

Tags: python, binary

Im trying to figure out how to check if the input consists of only "0" and "1". Been stuck on this for abit now, im quite new to python. I got the inverse part down, just need help with the check. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323364/in-python-how-to-check-if-a-string-only-contains-certain-characters

Comment: `set(my_string) <= {'0', '1'}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can cast it to `set()` and check if it only contains "0" and "1"

```py
value = "001001"
binary = set(value) <= {"0", "1"}

print(binary)
```

Result:

```sh
True
```

Trying with different values from "0" and "1":

```py
value = "hello"
binary = set(value) <= {"0", "1"}

print(binary)
```

Result:

```sh
False
```