# Potential errors with my makeValidFilename function?

Tags: python, filesystems, sanitization, file-rename

It is inspired by ["How to make a valid Windows filename from an arbitrary string?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295135/turn-a-string-into-a-valid-filename-in-python), I've written a function that will take arbitrary string and make it a valid filename.

My function should technically be an answer to this question, but I want to make sure I've not done anything stupid, or overlooked anything, before posting it as an answer.

I wrote this as part of [tvnamer](http://github.com/dbr/tvnamer) - a utility which takes TV episode filenames, and renames them nice and consistently, with an episode pulled from http://www.thetvdb.com - while the source filename must be a valid file, the series name is corrected, and the episode name - so both could contain theoretically any characters. I'm not so much concerned about security as usability - it's mainly to prevent files being renamed `.some.series - [01x01].avi` and the file "disappearing" (rather than to thwart evil people)

It makes a few assumptions:

- The filesystem supports Unicode filenames. HFS+ and NTFS both do, which will cover a majority of users. There is also a `normalize_unicode` argument to strip out Unicode characters (in tvnamer, this is set via the config XML file)
- The platform is either Darwin, Linux, and everything else is treated as Windows
- The filename is intended to be visible (not a dotfile like `.bashrc`) - it would be simple enough to modify the code to allow `.abc` format filenames, if desired

Things I've (hopefully) handled:

- Prepend underscore if filename starts with `.` (prevents filenames `.` `..` and files from disappearing)
- Remove directory separators: `/` on Linux, and `/` and `:` on OS X
- Removing invalid Windows filename characters `\/:*?"<>|` (when on Windows, or forced with `windows_safe=True`)
- Prepend reserved filenames with underscore (`COM2` becomes `_COM2`, `NUL` becomes `_NUL` etc)
- Optional normalisation of Unicode data, so `å` becomes `a` and non-convertable characters are removed
- Truncation of filenames over 255 characters on Linux/Darwin, and 32 characters on Windows

The code and a bunch of test-cases can be found and fiddled with at http://gist.github.com/256270. The "production" code can be found [in tvnamer/utils.py](http://github.com/dbr/tvnamer/blob/master/tvnamer/utils.py#L256-324)

Is there any errors with this function? Any conditions I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

One point I've noticed: Under NTFS, some files can not be created in specific directories.
E.G. $Boot in root