# Python function to make arbitrary strings valid filenames

Tags: python, windows, string, filenames

Is there a built-in function which strips all characters which cannot be in Windows filenames from a string or replaces them somehow?

E.g. `function("Some:unicode\symbols")` --> `"Some-unicode-symbols"`

Comment: "all characters"?  ASCII?  Or Unicode?  Replaces them "somehow"?  Any specific suggestions on what you'd like to see?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll edit it accordingly.

Comment: Possible answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295135/turn-a-string-into-a-valid-filename-in-python

Comment: Interesting but not an answer, whitelist is impossible for unicode, and blacklist is not portable (although if it won't work otherwise, I'll resort to a blacklist).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import re

arbitrary_string = "File!name?.txt"
cleaned_up_filename = re.sub(r'[/\\:*?"<>|]', '', arbitrary_string)
filepath = os.path.join("/tmp", cleaned_up_filename)

with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
    # ...
```

Taken from User [gx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21580/gx) 
Obviously adapt to your situation.