# How to remove unsafe characters to save file

Tags: python, windows, regex, string, validation

I would like to save a file with the name that has the **most valid characters** remaining intact, f.e. if I get supplied the filename:

`>This\ Ăwesomé_Song?©.mp3`

and I want to save it under `Windows 7`, it won't let me save it until I remove `>`, `\` and `?`. The characters `Ă`, `©` and `é` are totally fine and I would like to keep them intact (instead of f.e. just running everything through an `ASCII` filter).

I don't know which characters are allowed f.e. under `Unix` and the like but I would like it to work *platform-independently*. The way I would solve this problem is by implementing a list of strings that each contain a class of characters, ranked from most vicious (f.e. `?`) to most harmless (f.e. the letter `a`) and knocking them out string by string until I get a filename that i can save.

Language is `Python`, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295135/turn-a-string-into-a-valid-filename-in-python is a very similar question. take a look

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.sub(r'[\\/:"*?<>|]+', "", "This\ Ăwesomé_Song?©.mp3")
This Ăwesomé_Song©.mp3
>>>
```

Comment: I was able to easily adapt this solution for Groovy (and handle few extra characters for my own needs):

filename = filename.replaceAll(~/[\\/:"*?<>| #,]+/, '-')

Answer (score 1):

In posix, only two octets are reserved, forward slash (`/`, 0x2F, dec 42), and null (`\0`, 0x00, dec 0).  Any other character could appear in a filename.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this pattern from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295135/turn-a-string-into-a-valid-filename-in-python) question to list all valid characters:

```
>>> import string
>>> valid_chars = "-_.() %s%s" % (string.ascii_letters, string.digits)
```

And then just check your filename manually.