# Python: get list of characters inapplicable for file naming?

Tags: python, filesystems

In a Python script I want to know which characters are inapplicable for use in file names under current OS/FileSystem. I'd like to create files without errors. Is there such feature in Python?

Comment: Are you aware that that list could be really long? On a FAT system, it would probably encompass >99% of Unicode.

Comment: Stick to ASCII, it's a safe bet on any current OS/fs.

Comment: 9000, how about "\/?" - they are ASCII, but still unwanted on FAT.

Comment: character don't get "[deprecated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecated)"

Comment: the comments by @phihag and 9000 are on the right track: define or find a whitelist of characters: a subset of acceptable characters for you. That way, you cut down on processing, and you are sure of what you're going to get.

Comment: @9000 unless the OS uses EBCDIC. Could happen. Still, most programs will have worse problems in an environment like that.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer a question with another question, but this question seems to be what you are looking for: [turn a string into a valid filename in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295135/turn-a-string-into-a-valid-filename-in-python). Otherwise, the list of reserved characters by OS is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words).