# Convert url to unique hashed code to save html file

Tags: python, hash

Hi i am looking to save the html of urls. In an ideal world I would use the url as the file name - however given urls often contain special characters, this is not going to be possible.

What i want is a way of converting the url into a 'code' which can then use as the file name. I also need a way of being able to go back as well (i.e. from the file name to the original url).

I am assuming that the best way of doing this is hashing in some way, but not sure where to start. I will be working in Python, so ideally want something of the form:

```
 def url_to_file_name ():
     ...

     return (file_name)

 def file_name_to_url ():
    ...

    return (url)
```

Comment: Hashing is a one way operation. Is it acceptable to fully escape (into unicode values for example) these chars from your filename?

Comment: @sobolevn ideally yes - but given your comment, on-balance, I may just therefore hash, and accept that i won't be able to go back from the file name to get the original url.

Comment: then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295135/turn-a-string-into-a-valid-filename-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use the url encode method, it would convert most(as per my knowledge) to '%' chars + alphanumbers and dots.

Eg: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

You can use:

```
urllib.quote_plus("stackoverflow.com?it!@#$%^&*()cool")
```

Hashing might not be a good solution as you won't be able to convert back.