# How to fixing scrapy json row to multiple json file

Tags: python, scrapy

I have created a scrapy crawler to export individual item to a folder called out but I got 58 items from crawler but not getting 58 files. We just found 50 files.

Currently, I am using windows 10 and python 3

```py
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


    import json
    import os
    import random
    from scrapy import Spider
    from scrapy.http import Request

    class AndroiddeviceSpider(Spider):
        name = 'androiddevice'
        allowed_domains = ['androiddevice.info']
        start_urls = ['']

        def __init__(self,sr_term):

            self.start_urls=['https://www.androiddevice.info/devices?search='+sr_term]


        def parse(self, response):
            print (response.url)
            print ('\n')

            listings = response.css('a:nth-of-type(2)::attr(href)').extract()

            for link in listings:
                ac_link = response.urljoin(link)

                sum_meta = link.split('/')[-1]

                yield Request(ac_link, meta={"sum_meta":sum_meta}, callback=self.parse_p)
                # yield scrapy.Request(ac_link, callback=self.parse_p)



            # checking_last = response.xpath('//*[contains(text(),"Last")]').xpath('.//@href').extract_first()

            # if checking_last:
            #     checking_last = checking_last.split('?page=')[-1].split('&')[0]

            #     ran_ = int(checking_last)+1


            # if int(checking_last) is not 1:
            #     for i in range(2, ran_):
            #         next_p = 'https://www.androiddevice.info/devices?page={}&search=samsung'.format(i)

            #         n_link = next_p
            #         yield Request(n_link, callback=self.parse)


        def parse_p(self, response):
            sum_meta = response.meta['sum_meta']

            r = response.url
            r = r.split('/')[-2]

            sum_meta = r

            listings = response.css('th a::attr(href)').extract()

            for link in listings:
                ac_link = response.urljoin(link)

                yield Request(ac_link, callback=self.parse_details)



            checking_last = response.xpath('//*[contains(text(),"Last")]').xpath('.//@href').extract_first()

            if checking_last:
                checking_last = checking_last.split('?page=')[-1].split('&')[0]

                ran_ = int(checking_last)+1


            if int(checking_last) is not 1:
                for i in range(2, ran_):
                    # next_p = 'https://www.androiddevice.info/devices?page={}&search=samsung'.format(i)
                    next_p = 'https://www.androiddevice.info/submissions/{}'+'?page={}'.format(sum_meta,i)

                    n_link = next_p
                    yield Request(n_link, callback=self.parse_p)



        def parse_details(self, response):


            url = response.url

            print (url)
            print ('\n')

            item = {}

            items = item

            timezone_olson_random = [
                "America/Indiana/Knox",
                "America/Denver",
                "America/Kentucky/Monticello",
                "America/Detroit",
                "America/Indiana/Petersburg",
                "America/New_York",
                "America/Chicago",
                "America/Kentucky/Louisville",
                "America/Los_Angeles",
                "America/Indianapolis",

            ]


            java_vm_version = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"java_vm_version")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
            ro_product_provider = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro.product.manufacturer")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
            ro_product_brand = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro.product.manufacturer")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
            ro_product_name = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro.product.name")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
            ro_product_model = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro.product.model")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
            ro_product_board = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro.product.board")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
            ro_build_id = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro_build_id")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
            ro_build_version_incremental = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro_build_version_incremental")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
            ro_build_version_release = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro_build_version_release")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
            ro_build_version_sdk = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro_build_version_sdk")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
            timezone_olson = random.choice(timezone_olson_random)



            item['java_vm_version'] = java_vm_version
            item['ro_product_provider'] = ro_product_provider
            item['ro_product_brand'] = ro_product_brand
            item['ro_product_name'] = ro_product_name
            item['ro_product_model'] = ro_product_model
            item['ro_product_board'] = ro_product_board
            item['ro_build_id'] = ro_build_id
            item['ro_build_version_incremental'] = ro_build_version_incremental
            item['ro_build_version_release'] = ro_build_version_release
            item['ro_build_version_sdk'] = ro_build_version_sdk
            item['timezone_olson'] = timezone_olson

            formatted_json = json.dumps(items, indent = 4,sort_keys=True)
            with open(os.path.join('out', ro_product_model+".json"), "w") as f:
                f.write(formatted_json)

            yield item
```

I expect the output files would be 58 items to 58 .json files into my out folder

Thank you,
Palash

Comment: You may have duplicate *no_product_model*, so that some files are overwritten.

Comment: i got the solution. thanks

Comment: we found one error just now

Comment: device.py", line 142, in parse_details
with open(os.path.join('out', ro_product_model_created+".json"), "w") as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'out\\?? (1.6.0-Nokia ????-Lumia925-TL1263-TL1263-S001-DESAY_TL1263_15012_140611-4.3-18).json'

Comment: @palashbabu there are probably restrictions on windows concerning file names that forbid this name. I found not possible to open a file starting by '?' in windows 10.

Comment: As for turning a string into a valid filename, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/295135/939364