# How to fixing OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm setting up a scrapy spider on my windows 10 machine and it's running pretty fine! but my problem is when it's finish the last item showing on :

```
device.py, line 142, in parse_details
    with open(os.path.join('out', ro_product_model_created+".json"), "w") as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'out\\?? (1.6.0-Nokia ????-Lumia925-TL1263-TL1263-S001-DESAY_TL1263_15012_140611-4.3-18).json'
```

I am using python 3.6

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import os
import random
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request

class AndroiddeviceSpider(Spider):
    name = 'androiddevice'
    allowed_domains = ['androiddevice.info']
    start_urls = ['']

    def __init__(self,sr_term):
        self.start_urls=['https://www.androiddevice.info/devices?search='+sr_term]

    def parse(self, response):
        print (response.url)
        print ('\n')

        listings = response.css('a:nth-of-type(2)::attr(href)').extract()

        for link in listings:
            ac_link = response.urljoin(link)

            sum_meta = link.split('/')[-1]

            yield Request(ac_link, meta={"sum_meta":sum_meta}, callback=self.parse_p)
            # yield scrapy.Request(ac_link, callback=self.parse_p)

        checking_last = response.xpath('//*[contains(text(),"Last")]').xpath('.//@href').extract_first()

        if checking_last:
            checking_last = checking_last.split('?page=')[-1].split('&')[0]
            ran_ = int(checking_last)+1

        if int(checking_last) is not 1:
            for i in range(2, ran_):
                next_p = 'https://www.androiddevice.info/devices?page={}&search=samsung'.format(i)

                n_link = next_p
                yield Request(n_link, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_p(self, response):
        sum_meta = response.meta['sum_meta']

        r = response.url
        r = r.split('/')[-2]

        sum_meta = r

        listings = response.css('th a::attr(href)').extract()

        for link in listings:
            ac_link = response.urljoin(link)

            yield Request(ac_link, callback=self.parse_details)

        checking_last = response.xpath('//*[contains(text(),"Last")]').xpath('.//@href').extract_first()

        if checking_last:
            checking_last = checking_last.split('?page=')[-1].split('&')[0]
            ran_ = int(checking_last)+1

        if int(checking_last) is not 1:
            for i in range(2, ran_):
                # next_p = 'https://www.androiddevice.info/devices?page={}&search=samsung'.format(i)
                next_p = 'https://www.androiddevice.info/submissions/{}'+'?page={}'.format(sum_meta,i)

                n_link = next_p
                yield Request(n_link, callback=self.parse_p)

    def parse_details(self, response):
        url = response.url

        print (url)
        print ('\n')

        item = {}

        items = item

        timezone_olson_random = [
            "America/Indiana/Knox",
            "America/Denver",
            "America/Kentucky/Monticello",
            "America/Detroit",
            "America/Indiana/Petersburg",
            "America/New_York",
            "America/Chicago",
            "America/Kentucky/Louisville",
            "America/Los_Angeles",
            "America/Indianapolis",

        ]

        java_vm_version = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"java_vm_version")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
        ro_product_provider = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro.product.manufacturer")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
        ro_product_brand = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro.product.manufacturer")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
        ro_product_name = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro.product.name")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
        ro_product_model = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro.product.model")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
        ro_product_board = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro.product.board")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
        ro_build_id = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro_build_id")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
        ro_build_version_incremental = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro_build_version_incremental")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
        ro_build_version_release = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro_build_version_release")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
        ro_build_version_sdk = response.xpath('//tr//th[contains(text(),"ro_build_version_sdk")]//following-sibling::th//pre//text()').extract_first()
        timezone_olson = random.choice(timezone_olson_random)

        item['java_vm_version'] = java_vm_version
        item['ro_product_provider'] = ro_product_provider
        item['ro_product_brand'] = ro_product_brand
        item['ro_product_name'] = ro_product_name
        item['ro_product_model'] = ro_product_model
        item['ro_product_board'] = ro_product_board
        item['ro_build_id'] = ro_build_id
        item['ro_build_version_incremental'] = ro_build_version_incremental
        item['ro_build_version_release'] = ro_build_version_release
        item['ro_build_version_sdk'] = ro_build_version_sdk
        item['timezone_olson'] = timezone_olson


        ro_product_model_created = ro_product_model+' ('+java_vm_version+'-'+ro_product_brand+'-'+ro_product_name+'-'+ro_product_board+'-'+ro_build_id+'-'+ro_build_version_incremental+'-'+ro_build_version_release+'-'+ro_build_version_sdk+')'

        formatted_json = json.dumps(items, indent = 4,sort_keys=True)
        with open(os.path.join('out', ro_product_model_created+".json"), "w") as f:
            f.write(formatted_json)

        yield item
```

I expect the output wouldn't be getting any error. 
It's actually scraped individual file from each row of json into out folder.

Run it on cmd:

```
scrapy crawl androiddevice -a sr_term=nokia
```

Thanks,
Palash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sanitizing your filenames here:

```
with open(os.path.join('out', ro_product_model_created+".json"), "w") as f:
#                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    f.write(formatted_json)
```

`ro_product_model_created` in your case contains `//?` etc. which are not valid filename characters

For sanitizing filename see related question: [Turn a string into a valid filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295135/turn-a-string-into-a-valid-filename)

My personal preference is:

```
ro_product_model_created = "".join(x for x in s if x.isalnum())
```