# Save Pytorch model state_dict with datetime in filename

Tags: python, pytorch, state-dict

I've been trying to save the state_dict of a Pytorch model with 
`torch.save(agent.qnetwork_local.state_dict(), filename)` where 
 `filename = datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%y-%H:%M_dqnweights.pth')`

`type(filename)` returns `str` which shouldn't be a problem with `torch.save()` and it should output a non-empty file. Instead I get an empty file with just the date and time and nothing after that. Putting the date and in the middle of the filename results in an empty file with everything after the date and time cut off.

`torch.save(agent.qnetwork_local.state_dict(), 'checkpoint1.pth')` and any time I hardcode the string works and gives me the expected non-empty file.

What is going on and how do I fix this?

I am running this code in a Python v3.6.8 virtualenv with Pytorch v1.8.1+cpu on Windows 10.

Comment: What is your OS? Windows?

Comment: Yes WIndows 10. Editing the question now.

Comment: I think colon is not allowed in Windows filenames. Try without it.

Comment: It worked. I had presumed that any filename problems would just throw an error instead of saving an empty file. Is there a exception or some other mechanism that I can use to prevent writing the file if it is incompatible with the conventions of the operating system the program is running on?

Comment: Nothing that is built in, AFAIK. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295135/turn-a-string-into-a-valid-filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colon was the problem in `filename = datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%y-%H:%m_dqnweights.pth')` since it was running on windows.

Changing it to `filename = datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%y-%H_%M_dqnweights.pth')` works as expected.

Comment: Note that the minute is wrong. It should be `%M`, otherwise it will output the month again.

Comment: Oops. Fixed it. Thank you.