# how to use pytube to download Youtube playlist with numeric videos

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I don`t know what is the problem in my code
i wanna download youtube playlist with numeric

```
from pytube import Playlist
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
playlist = Playlist(input("input the link:\n"))
folder_name = filedialog.askdirectory()
print("print total videos in playlist :", len(playlist.video_urls))
v = 1
for video in playlist.videos:
    video.streams.get_by_resolution('360p').download(folder_name) ##remove video.title+str(v)
    os.rename( video.streams.get_by_resolution('360p').default_filename,str(v)+video.title)
    print("Video Downloaded: ", video.title)
    v += 1
```

And the problem message is

```
C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\yt_playlist.py 
input the link:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWlltQ6Oy0zpgxVhd2vZqTDvVXpPhSVd0
print total videos in playlist : 8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\yt_playlist.py", line 10, in <module>
    os.rename( video.streams.get_by_resolution('360p').default_filename,str(v)+video.title)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'What is Sustainable Agriculture Episode 1 A Whole-Farm Approach to Sustainability.mp4' -> '1What is Sustainable Agriculture? Episode 1: A Whole-Farm Approach to Sustainability'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried this code and didn`t work

```
from pytube import Playlist
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
playlist = Playlist(input("input the link:\n"))
folder_name = filedialog.askdirectory()
print("print total videos in playlist :", len(playlist.video_urls))
v = 1
for video in playlist.videos:
    video.streams.get_by_resolution('360p').download(folder_name)
    os.chdir(folder_name)
    os.rename( video.streams.get_by_resolution('360p').default_filename,str(v)+video.title)
    print("Video Downloaded: ", video.title)
    v += 1
```

it shows this problem

```
C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\yt_playlist.py 
input the link:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWlltQ6Oy0zpgxVhd2vZqTDvVXpPhSVd0
print total videos in playlist : 8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\yt_playlist.py", line 11, in <module>
    os.rename( video.streams.get_by_resolution('360p').default_filename,str(v)+video.title)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'What is Sustainable Agriculture Episode 1 A Whole-Farm Approach to Sustainability.mp4' -> '1What is Sustainable Agriculture? Episode 1: A Whole-Farm Approach to Sustainability'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

just to know it works with just video not playlists (that`s what happend with me)

Answer (score 0):

You have the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'What is Sustainable Agriculture Episode 1 A Whole-Farm Approach to Sustainability.mp4' -> '1What is Sustainable Agriculture? Episode 1: A Whole-Farm Approach to Sustainability'
```

However when looking in your `folder_name` directory, you see the file `What is Sustainable Agriculture Episode 1 A Whole-Farm Approach to Sustainability.mp4`. So `os.rename` source file is specified in an incorrect directory. Indeed `video.streams.get_by_resolution('360p').default_filename` isn't taking care of your `folder_name`.

So to solve your issue you can just move your [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) to `folder_name` by using `os.chdir(folder_name)` just after `folder_name` assignment (`folder_name = filedialog.askdirectory()`).

So your code should become:

```
from pytube import Playlist
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
playlist = Playlist(input("input the link:\n"))
folder_name = filedialog.askdirectory()
os.chdir(folder_name)
print("print total videos in playlist :", len(playlist.video_urls))
v = 1
for video in playlist.videos:
    video.streams.get_by_resolution('360p').download(folder_name)
    os.rename( video.streams.get_by_resolution('360p').default_filename,str(v)+video.title)
    print("Video Downloaded: ", video.title)
    v += 1
```

Comment: look at my edit ,please
it didn`t work

Comment: [I edited my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74047046/revisions) as you misplaced `os.chdir(folder_name)`. Note that your new error is different from the old one `OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'What is Sustainable Agriculture Episode 1 A Whole-Farm Approach to Sustainability.mp4' -> '1What is Sustainable Agriculture? Episode 1: A Whole-Farm Approach to Sustainability'` I suspect that your OS doesn't support filename with  `?` or `:`.

Comment: [This problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295135/7123660) was already raised on StackOverflow, have a look at its answers.