# Android GCM unicode charcters are not received

Tags: android, unicode, google-cloud-messaging

This is my server side code or android side code.
This code is working fine only for English messages. If I use Unicode charters like use Arabic language then it shows nothing in place of Arabic.
In cause of English Arabic mix, it skip the only Arabic charters.

Kindly give me solution.
Thanks!

This is my C# code

```
private string SendNotification(string authstring, string id, string msg)
    {
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";

            request.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", authstring));
            string collaspeKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");
            string postData = string.Format("registration_id={0}&data.payload={1}&collapse_key={2}", id, msg, collaspeKey);
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();

            return responseFromServer;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

And this is my Android side code that catch the message.

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {        
    String message = ArabicUtilities.reshape(intent.getExtras().getString("payload"));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the answer and I am not a C# programmer. But based on what I understood of your code you are not encoding the strings. For instance `http://www.acom?q=some data` is invalid . You had to encode "some data" yielding `http://www.acom?q=some%20data`. I guess that you have to encode the Arabic characters too. In python I would use `cgi.encode()` and in Java `UrlEnconder.encode()`. I don't know the equivalent in C#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[André Oriani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1525801/andre-oriani)
has the general idea for the fix.  Even though the message is placed in the body of the request, it still needs to url encoded.

```
string postData = string.Format("registration_id={0}&data.payload={1}&collapse_key={2}", id, msg, collaspeKey);
```

should be replaced with

```
string postData = string.Format("registration_id={0}&data.payload={1}&collapse_key={2}", id, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(msg), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(collaspeKey));
```

You will need to add a reference to System.Web in order to use HttpUtility.  See [URL Encoding using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp) for more information.

Comment: is there a something like HTTPUtility this for java?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using base64 to encode the string sent through GCM?  This way you would remove all encoding problems.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what solved it for me in Java:

On the server side:

```
encodedMessage = URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8");
```

In the app:

```
decodedMessage = URLDecoder.decode(message, "UTF-8");
```