# GCM and Special characters

Tags: android, google-app-engine, special-characters, google-cloud-messaging

I recently changed my c2dm push aaplucation to GCM. A new problem appeared. Its now receiving  `'?'` instead of `'ö','ï', ...`

My server logs correct Strings, but the application receives '?' insteads.

Do you think it could have something to do with GCM?

My code is the following:

```
public static void displayMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String message = (String) extras.get("message");
        Log.v("extras", extras.toString());
        Util.generateNotification(context, message, intent);
    }
}
```

and the log is then:

```
10-02 22:18:23.671: V/intent(29809): Bundle[{message={"name":"j?rg"},
message_id=8bb60eee-3a93-4075-b606-40495511a4da, collapse_key=do_not_collapse, from=160085429222}]
```

Best regards!

Comment: I could use an URLEncoder/Decoder... Is there another way?

Comment: Make sure it's not an artifact of the logging.

Comment: I'm sure. The special/Latin1 characters are simply replaced by '?'. It worked perfectly with c2dm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think so there is problem in GCM. Try to use UTFEncoding for your message.

```
String output = new String(name.getBytes("8859_1"), "utf-8");
```

Comment: Converting to UTF-8 does not work. This could be the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501504/android-gcm-unicode-charcters-are-not-received