# How to send a Firebase Cloud Messaging Notification with special characters like ä, ö, ü?

Tags: firebase, web-applications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried for a while to send a FCM Notification with special characters like this:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=Auth-CODE" 
--header Content-Type:"application/json 
for JSON; application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" 
-d '{"to":"token","notification":{"title":"München",
"body":"Test Content with äöü",
"icon":"images/icon-192x192.png"}}' 
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

The notification I'll get looks like this:

```
Mnchen
Test Content with
```

Can anybody please guide me to the right direction?
Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

The client is a browser, because the app is a web-App.

Comment: Have you seen these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12704567/4625829, http://stackoverflow.com/q/11501504/4625829?

Comment: yes I tried this also...
first urlencode the string and finally url_decode the received string... This always shows me *M%C3%BCnchen*

Comment: Are you using Android as a Client App?

Comment: Try with Base64 encode/decode.

Comment: @AL. The client is a browser, because the app is a web-App. (sorry I missed this info!)

Comment: @LạngHoàng Thanks a lot! It seems to me that the changes need some time to take effect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @LangHoang I tried to use Base64 encode and decode to get a special character support!

```
<?php 
base64_encode ($string);
```

and decode the response in javascript (firebase-messaging-sw.js)

```
body:b64DecodeUnicode(payload.notification.body)
```

And now everything works very well!

Answer (score 1):

With `application/json;charset=UTF-8` should work. Had the same issue, that adding `charset=UTF-8` to the `Content-Type` solved it.