# FCM Push Notification is not supporting Special Characters (& - / * ) - Android Notification?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM Push Notification for retrieving updates from firebase .
Notification works fine but when the notification content contains special characters( & * "" - ) , the notification shows some series of integer values instead of special characters .

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a Firebase Cloud Messaging Notification with special characters like ä, ö, ü?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115769/how-to-send-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-with-special-characters-like)

Comment: it happened the same in me with web push notification. Api is working but when I add \n, for example, it doesn't work... just sending message from textarea in Mvc and c#