# Detect and escape all special char

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a string, that is used to send into a mailto.

I want to find all special char, and then escape them, to make my mailto work good, without avoid the choice to wrote special char.

For exemple, if my string contains a `#`, the body of my mailto will stop before it.

```
String strCmd = String.Format("window.open(\"mailto:{0}?subject={1}&body={2}\");",
                    toEmail, subject, body);
```

If  my string body is like :

```
body = "This is a string to test c# code with a mailto";
```

Then the mailto will contain `This is a string to test c`.

How can I fix this, to obtain `This is a string to test c# code with a mailto`?

It must also made the backLine if there is.

Thank you.

Comment: my suggestion would be to use Regex and find all the special characters and replace them with it formatted correctly.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for. But do not found how to do this.

Comment: Using Regex to create a valid URL is not trivial. Trying to escape all characters is even more difficult. .NET already has methods for encoding string as valid URLs or HTML

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL Encoding using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really about escaping special characters but encoding a string as a valid URL than can be handled by the javascript call `window.open`. Even "normal" characters like <, >, are considered special when working with URLs.

Luckily, .NET can already encode a string as a URL with [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx). This call will replace special characters like < and > with their URL encode values %3c and %3e.

You should take care to encode only the parameters you pass to String.Format, not the entire formatted string, as UrlEncode will encode the entire string, including the ? and & characters:

```
String strCmd = String.Format("window.open(\"mailto:{0}?subject={1}&body={2}\");",
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(toEmail), 
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(subject), 
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(body));
```

Comment: Well, this also escape space, backspace... So got a title like `mail+to+friend`, worst for the message... Can i just found all special char and escape them, instead of Encoding all my string?

Comment: Encode only the parameters, not the entire script. See the code

Comment: Yes I know. And that's what I do.

Comment: What do you mean backline? Do you mean backslash? HttpUtility.UrlEncode escapes both slashes. \ becomes %5c and / becomes %2f.

Comment: backline = \r ? I don't know the word in english.

Comment: If you want to send multiline messages you are better off doing this on the server, rather than forcing the browser to send the message.
In any case, the character is called the linefeed, encoded as %0A. UrlEncode encodes it properly, as it does with the carriage return, \n as \%0d. Are you sure you CAN encode the message you want as a URL in the first place?

Comment: The message I want to encode is just a string. So, when i wrote my string, for a lineFeed, I must write \n, and it will be correctly convert?