# Algorithm to code URL

Tags: c#, algorithm, encoding, base64

is there some algorithm in C# to encode url with symbols that can correct display in web-browser?

something like **Base64**.

Comment: i search other algrithms, base64 i already use:)

Comment: I typed "C# url encode" into a search engine and the first result answers your question. Please show a little more effort in your questions.

Comment: Welcome! There are several methods, each with subtly different behaviour. They've been discussed at length in other questions though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11236038/1344760

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Standard ([RFC 3986](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) aka [STD 66](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/std66)) lays it out for you. In particular, §2 and 2.1:

> **2. Characters**
>
> The URI syntax provides a method of encoding data, presumably for the
>   sake of identifying a resource, as a sequence of characters.  The URI
>   characters are, in turn, frequently encoded as octets for transport
>   or presentation.  This specification does not mandate any particular
>   character encoding for mapping between URI characters and the octets
>   used to store or transmit those characters.  When a URI appears in a
>   protocol element, the character encoding is defined by that protocol;
>   without such a definition, a URI is assumed to be in the same
>   character encoding as the surrounding text.
>
> The ABNF notation defines its terminal values to be non-negative
>   integers (codepoints) based on the US-ASCII coded character set
>   [ASCII].  Because a URI is a sequence of characters, we must invert
>   that relation in order to understand the URI syntax.  Therefore, the
>   integer values used by the ABNF must be mapped back to their
>   corresponding characters via US-ASCII in order to complete the syntax
>   rules.
>
> A URI is composed from a limited set of characters consisting of
>   digits, letters, and a few graphic symbols.  A reserved subset of
>   those characters may be used to delimit syntax components within a
>   URI while the remaining characters, including both the unreserved set
>   and those reserved characters not acting as delimiters, define each
>   component's identifying data.
>
> *2.1.  Percent-Encoding*
>
> A percent-encoding mechanism is used to represent a data octet in a
>   component when that octet's corresponding character is outside the
>   allowed set or is being used as a delimiter of, or within, the
>   component.  A percent-encoded octet is encoded as a character
>   triplet, consisting of the percent character "%" followed by the two
>   hexadecimal digits representing that octet's numeric value.  For
>   example, "%20" is the percent-encoding for the binary octet
>   "00100000" (ABNF: %x20), which in US-ASCII corresponds to the space
>   character (SP).  Section 2.4 describes when percent-encoding and
>   decoding is applied.
>
> pct-encoded = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
>
> The uppercase hexadecimal digits 'A' through 'F' are equivalent to
>   the lowercase digits 'a' through 'f', respectively.  If two URIs
>   differ only in the case of hexadecimal digits used in percent-encoded
>   octets, they are equivalent.  For consistency, URI producers and
>   normalizers should use uppercase hexadecimal digits for all percent-
>   encodings.

In general, the only characters that may freely be represented in a URL **without** being percent-encoded are

- The **unreserved characters**. These are the US-ASCII (7-bit) characters

  - `A`-`Z`
  - `a`-`z`
  - `0`-`9`
  - `-._~`
- The **reserved characters** ... **when in use as within their role in the grammar** of a URL and its scheme. These reserved characters are:

  - `:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=`

Any other characters, per the standard must be properly percent-encoded.

Further note that a URL may only contains characters drawn from the US-ASCII character set (0x00-0x7F): If your URL contains characters outside that range of codepoints, those characters will need to be suitably encoded for representation in US-ASCII (e.g., via HTML/XML entity references). Further, you application is responsible for interpreting such.