# Textbox value in other textbox by clicking button not correct

Tags: c#, textbox

This program have a link which is fixed and never change. And it contains 5 textboxes. The fixed link is:

```
<seite>utm_source=<website>_<page>_de&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=<kampagne>&utm_content=<format>
```

Every value in `<>` should be changed by textbox value. Here you got an image of my little program:

[image]

Now my problem is: the first value is correct, but the other values aren't. So for example, if i type in second texbox: "website" it does not only replace `<website>` with "website". it replaced `<website>` with `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: website`.

My Code I tried:

```
private void btn_SendAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_FinishLink.Text = txt_Site.Text + "utm_source=" + txt_Website + "_" + txt_Page + "_de&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=" + txt_Campaign + "&utm_content=" + txt_Format;
        }
```

Comment: You need to use `.Text` after each of the textbox names to get the string in the TextBox.

Comment: You should use the text property of your textboxes, txt_Campaign.Text and so on.

Comment: I can't really tell from the code you've posted but I think your "txt_Website"  and the other ones too need to be "txt_Website.Text" and so on.

Comment: @Tim Why don't you post an answer instead of comment, when you provide a complete solution to the question?

Comment: Omg lol. What a bad mistake >.< It only has worked by first texbox because in this textbox I used `.Text`. It works. Thank you guys :) (Y)

Comment: @Andrew Because this is too simple

Comment: Yeah it was simple but I'm a newbie so I looked over it >.<

Comment: @Andrew - Because as you said, the complete solution fit in a comment.  If OP had not understood the comment, or if there was another problem that was not evident from the code and question then more explanation would have been needed and I would have put it as an answer.  In this case, the comment was enough for Roman to see the issue :)

Comment: @Tim But comments can't be accepted as an answer. So the question is destined to remain unanswered.

Comment: @weston - Now it's answered :)

Comment: @Tim twice! And neither will be accepted probably! But at least others can see it has answers I guess.

Comment: @weston - OP has accepted other answers, so don't be so sure.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the `Text` property of the `TextBox` needed to be used:

```
txt_FinishLink.Text = txt_Site.Text + "utm_source=" + txt_Website.Text + "_" + txt_Page.Text + "_de&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=" + txt_Campaign.Text + "&utm_content=" + txt_Format.Text
```

`Text` will return the string of characters in the specified `TextBox`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know what I had thought by writing this code. But it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void btn_SendAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt_FinishLink.Text = txt_Site.Text + "utm_source=" +
                          txt_Website.Text + "_" +
                          txt_Page.Text + "_de&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=" +
                          txt_Campaign.Text + "&utm_content=" +
                          txt_Format.Text;
}
```

Look at string.Format though, it makes it much easier to see the format of the new url:

```
private void btn_SendAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt_FinishLink.Text = string.Format(
            "{0}utm_source={1}_{2}_de&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign={3}&utm_content={4}",
             txt_Site.Text, //{0}
             txt_Website.Text,  //{1} etc.
             txt_Page.Text,
             txt_Campaign.Text,
             txt_Format.Text);

}
```

Then you may want to consider encoding the text before placing in the URL, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16894322/360211

Comment: +1 - Good points on using `String.Format` and encoding the text.