# URL is not rendering correctly in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, hyperlink, href

I have Hyperlink in a datalist. HTML is given below:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkEntry" runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
```

i have saved the URL of a Entry in the Database, like "http://test.com/posts/New-test-in-March" And used the following way to Bind it to Hyperlink in Item_databound of Datalist.

```
 lnkEntry.NavigateUrl = objEntry.PermaLink;
```

But when it renders into the browser the URL get changed to "**http%3a//test.com/posts/New-test-in-March**"

i have tried to use the URLDecode but it doesn't make any change in output.

```
 lnkEntry.NavigateUrl = Server.UrlDecode(objEntry.PermaLink);
```

Please help me how can i fix this issue.

Comment: Are you seeing the url in href as encoded or the content with in <a></a> encoded?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `HttpUtility`, like this:

```
 lnkEntry.NavigateUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(objEntry.PermaLink);
```

or `WebUtility` if running recent versions of .net.

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp/575843#575843) for more info.