# HttpUtility.UrlEncode vs Uri.EscapeUriString in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, uri, urlencode, url-encoding

I have a url string that I want to encode before passing it as an argument to the browser. I'm used the **"HttpUtility.UrlEncode"** function but found out that it doesn't encode all the URL, it doesn't take the query param.

For Example:

```
string url = "http://www.google.com?A --chrome-frame"
```

This function will not encode the space char after the parameter.

The **"Uri.EscapeUriString"** will encode the spacing but will it encode all other character that the **"UrlEncode"** function encode?,
Note that I can't use them both because this will break the URL.

Does:

```
string encodeUrl = Uri.EscapeUriString(url);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Uri uriObject = new Uri(url);
string encodeUrl = uriObject.AbsoluteUri;
```

Do you have other suggestions?

*Note that its not duplicate of "`Server.UrlEncode` vs. `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`" :)

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11236038/6116637