# How to put the exact string in the cookie using angularjs $cookies.put()

Tags: c#, angularjs, angular-cookies

In angular if I use

```
$cookies.put('key','{somedata}');
```

in cookies it comes like `%7Bsomedata%7D`
and when I access this from client side using `$cookies.get('key');` Its returning {somedata}. But When i try to access it from server side using C#
`Request.Cookies["key"]` Its returning `%7Bsomedata%7D` instead of `{somedata}.`

So I'm having issues when accessing these values in my c# code.

Please suggest me a way to set the cookie through angular so the I get the correct string in my C# code

Comment: Tried to reproduce your error. No success. Please have a look at this plnkr: [http://plnkr.co/edit/RiMXd6mRtByEHc0zxRz2?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/RiMXd6mRtByEHc0zxRz2?p=preview). Is there any difference? And how are you sending this string to your server - I guess C# is your server side language? Are you using the $cookies.get()-function?

Comment: @ilmgb Your angular js code in plnkr is exactly same. My actual problem is When i try to access it from server side using C# Request.Cookies["key"] Its returning %7Bsomedata%7D instead of {somedata} .

Comment: No experience with that, but a quick search what you try to achieve, found this, might help (I guess Decoding is what you are looking for) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp