# Url Path Encoding that actually works?

Tags: c#, urlencode

According to RFC 3986 the valid characters for the path component are:

```
a-z A-Z 0-9 . - _ ~ ! $ & ' ( ) * + , ; = : @
```

as well as percent-encoded characters and of course, the slash `/`.

I can however not find a class that converts a string to well formatted path according to above rules.

```
string rawPath = "/A9_(+@*)/# ?/";
string expectedPath = "/A9_(+@*)/%23%20%3f";
```

However, see code below:

```
string rawPath = "/A9_(+@*)/# ?/";
Uri.EscapeDataString(rawPath); //Output=>%2FA9_%28%2B%40%2A%29%2F%23%20%3F%2F
Uri.EscapeUriString(rawPath); //Ouput=>/A9_(+@*)/#%20?/
HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(rawPath); //Ouput=>/A9_(+@*)/#%20?/
```

Nothing I tried leaves allowed characters unescaped and propery escapes all other characters.

Hopefully somebody can save me from having to write my own utility!

Comment: Are you just trying to format is a certain way or is the URL not working?

Comment: Probably nobody who passes in a `#` or a `?` as part of a path expects you to escape it; they want you to treat them as delimiters. It's not really surprising that there's no pre-cooked method for this -- the sane thing to do is to not allow paths that include `#` or `?` as characters, regardless of whether they can be passed. (I wouldn't expect many web servers to treat this case correctly either, but that's another issue.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL Encoding using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/575440/5815327)

Answer (score 1):

Each of these provides an expected encoding based on various rules within the creation of the URI. This is because of the inclusion of Reserved Characters (See section 2.2 of RFC 3968), which include `?` and `#` which are delimiters defined by the standard. These would not be escaped because they are part of the language definition.

Comment: Not sure if I agree with this answer. (See section 3.3 of RFC 3968).
A path "segment" can be made up of:
`unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"`
Since `#` `?` and `space` is not on that list, you would expect that it needs to be percentage-encoded.