# Creating querystring with anchor link

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I have a controller that returns a redirect and I want to add an anchor link so it goes to a specific element. The problem I'm having is the element '#' gets converted to '%23'. I've tried encoding and decoding both # and %23 but it doesn't seem to work, so I feel like I'm missing something.

The code is:

```
return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage($"?success={success.ToString().ToLower()}"+"#sentletter");
```

I want the result to be

```
?success=true#sentletter
```

but it ends up as

```
?success=true%23sentletter
```

Thanks

Comment: did u tried `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode` and `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode`?

Comment: Yes, trying UrlDecode("%23sentletter") still gives me a url with %23 in it

Comment: I don't know if this will help with Umbraco, but you could try escaping it with a '/' (i.e., +"/#sentletter) to see if that works.

Comment: That actually seems to do the opposite, it returns %2f%23sentletter

Answer (score 1):

In server side you have various methods for URL encoding, [this info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11236038/5368671) is very useful for a encoding in server side, for cliente side you can check [this info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for more info.

Comment: Ok but this is encoding, and I believe I'm trying to do the opposite and decode