# How to properly encode a hyperlink to a document where filename contains spaces?

Tags: asp.net, .net, urlencode

Our web application uses hyperlinks to reference downloadable documents.  An issue recently arose where an apostrophe in the filename was breaking the `href` link, preventing it from being downloaded.

So I decided to encode the URL with `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` so that apostrophes are encoded as `%27`.  In the process, spaces were encoded as `+`'s like so:

`http://www.whatever.com/docs/My+Doc+With+Spaces.xls`

Whenever the URL is accessed via the link or copied and pasted into Chrome or Firefox's address bar, I get a 404.  However, when I manually replace the `+`'s with a space and hit enter, the document downloads as expected.  Oddly, immediately after the download, the URL reverts back to its original format using `+`'s which results in another 404 when I refresh the browser.  Don't get it... the browser doesn't like the `+`, but then decides that it does?

If I use `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode` then it will encode the spaces as `%20` which results in a working URL, but it doesn't encode the apostrophe, so I am back at square one.

I need the best of both worlds here.

So my questions are:

- How can I encode a document filename that has spaces and apostrophes (and all other legal filename characters in a Windows OS)
- Why won't a hyperlink with `+`'s work when opened directly?  How come when I replace with spaces, the browser reverts it back to use `+`'s?

Comment: I think Uri.EscapeDataString is the method you are looking for

Comment: @Kevin That encodes the space as `%20`, but does *not* encode the apostrophe.  An answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp suggests that it does, but my results with .NET 4.6.2 show otherwise.

Comment: This point of this whole quesiton could now be moot as the issue might just be with how WebForms assigns URIs to the `href` attribute of a link.  When I edit the HTML source with Chrome's inspect, the `'` works fine.  What I think I will do is explicitly replace `'` with `%27` in the code.  I tried this and it works.

Comment: As the answer below it works for me too...

Answer (score 2):

I have tried both on .NET 4.5 and .NET 4.6.2

```
Uri.EscapeDataString("My Doc Wi'th Spaces.xls");
```

returns **My%20Doc%20Wi%27th%20Spaces.xls**

Just the value should be the last part of the URL, otherwise "**:**" and "**/**" also would be encoded