# can't replace " " (space) with + (plus) in a string

Tags: c#, string, api, asp.net-web-api

I am new to c# ,Here I am sending a string as a parameter of a API method .

Before that I have converted a password in API as a hashed string to the database .Then I retrieve it from angular 4 and passing again it to API while receiving in Angular 4 I got the same string which I stored in database .

When I pass it to the API ,In API I received the string but it losses + symbols in it .

Specifically it loss all the **+** in the string .I have tried to replace space with + but it not working in this .

```
 string cc = mPasswordHash.Replace(" ", "+");
```

Passed String to API : **AhU29yCXdtoaNyQ8rhUBZMz0MieMNBTUaaA04hO+pGzd/iK01sQx6ckMi8LqCdyphShlBt9QhLtCizcUsy708eU90GD7Qg==**

Received String :

**AhU29yCXdtoaNyQ8rhUBZMz0MieMNBTUaaA04hO(here + is not there)pGzd/iK01sQx6ckMi8LqCdyphShlBt9QhLtCizcUsy708eU90GD7Qg==**

can anyone help me to solve this .

Comment: Try using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) when sending the value to the API (assuming you are doing this from javascript; are you?)

Comment: This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the request being sent you should [encode your URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI). This ensures special characters are transported to the destination server in a standardized format. C# has functions built in for encoding and decoding strings as well:

[`System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_WebUtility_UrlEncode_System_String_)

[`System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.7.2)