# How do you consume the querystring data which has abc%5Bxyz%5D?

Tags: c#

It's easier to consume the data with the query string 
http://www.contoso.com/student?id=12345

But how do you consume the data with abc%5Bname%5D on the controller?
http://www.contoso.com/student?abc%5Bname%5D=john

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL Encoding using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You want [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urldecode?view=netcore-3.1#System_Web_HttpUtility_UrlDecode_System_String_)

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/student?abc%5Bname%5D=john";
url = HttpUtlity.UrlDecode(url);
```

Comment: How do you consume this on the API controller? if the request is coming to your local host?